# Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, faq, c#-faq

Когда я выполняю некоторый код, выбрасывается исключение `NullReferenceException` со следующим сообщением:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

или

> В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект.

Что это значит, и как мне исправить код?

Comment: Добавил важный каноничный ответ с английского SO [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Теперь можно закрывать большинство вопросов про NRE как дубль, а не ковыряться с каждым отдельным случаем. Всё равно почти всегда одно и то же.

Comment: Надо ещё про `?.` дополнить. Вроде не видно в ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Когда C# 6 релизнется — добавлю.

Comment: @Discord: Пора! C# 6 вышел.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/

Answer (score 119, accepted):

## Причина

### Вкратце

Вы пытаетесь воспользоваться чем-то, что равно `null` (или `Nothing` в VB.NET). Это означает, что либо вы присвоили это значение, либо вы ничего не присваивали.

Как и любое другое значение, `null` может передаваться от объекта к объекту, от метода к методу. Если нечто равно `null` в методе "А", вполне может быть, что метод "В" передал это значение в метод "А".

Остальная часть статьи описывает происходящее в деталях и перечисляет распространённые ошибки, которые могут привести к исключению `NullReferenceException`.

### Более подробно

Если среда выполнения выбрасывает исключение `NullReferenceException`, то это **всегда** означает одно: вы пытаетесь воспользоваться ссылкой. И эта ссылка не инициализирована (или *была* инициализирована, но *уже* не инициализирована).

Это означает, что ссылка равна `null`, а вы не сможете вызвать методы через ссылку, равную `null`. В простейшем случае:

```
string foo = null;
foo.ToUpper();
```

Этот код выбросит исключение `NullReferenceException` на второй строке, потому что вы не можете вызвать метод `ToUpper()` у ссылки на `string`, равной `null`.

## Отладка

Как определить источник ошибки? Кроме изучения, собственно, исключения, которое будет выброшено именно там, где оно произошло, вы можете воспользоваться общими рекомендациями по отладке в Visual Studio: поставьте точки останова в ключевых точках, [изучите значения переменных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/esta7c62.aspx), либо расположив курсор мыши над переменной, либо открыв панели для отладки: Watch, Locals, Autos.

Если вы хотите определить место, где значение ссылки устанавливается или не устанавливается, нажмите правой кнопкой на её имени и выберите "Find All References". Затем вы можете поставить точки останова на каждой найденной строке и запустить приложение в режиме отладки. Каждый раз, когда отладчик остановится на точке останова, вы можете удостовериться, что значение верное.

Следя за ходом выполнения программы, вы придёте к месту, где значение ссылки не должно быть `null`, и определите, почему не присвоено верное значение.

## Примеры

Несколько общих примеров, в которых возникает исключение.

#### Цепочка

```
ref1.ref2.ref3.member
```

Если `ref1`, `ref2` или `ref3` равно `null`, вы получите `NullReferenceException`. Для решения проблемы и определения, что именно равно `null`, вы можете переписать выражение более простым способом:

```
var r1 = ref1;
var r2 = r1.ref2;
var r3 = r2.ref3;
r3.member
```

Например, в цепочке `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, значение может отсутствовать и у `HttpContext.Current`, и у `User`, и у `Identity`.

#### Неявно

```
public class Person {
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class Book {
    public Person Author { get; set; }
}
public class Example {
    public void Foo() {
        Book b1 = new Book();
        int authorAge = b1.Author.Age; // Свойство Author не было инициализировано
                                       // нет Person, у которого можно вычислить Age.
    }
}
```

То же верно для вложенных инициализаторов:

```
Book b1 = new Book { Author = { Age = 45 } };
```

Несмотря на использование ключевого слова `new`, создаётся только экземпляр класса `Book`, но экземпляр `Person` не создаётся, поэтому свойство `Author` остаётся `null`.

#### Массив

```
int[] numbers = null;
int n = numbers[0]; // numbers = null. Нет массива, чтобы получить элемент по индексу
```

#### Элементы массива

```
Person[] people = new Person[5];
people[0].Age = 20; // people[0] = null. Массив создаётся, но не
                    // инициализируется. Нет Person, у которого можно задать Age.
```

#### Массив массивов

```
long[][] array = new long[1][];
array[0][0] = 3; // = null, потому что инициализировано только первое измерение.
                 // Сначала выполните array[0] = new long[2].
```

#### Collection/List/Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> agesForNames = null;
int age = agesForNames["Bob"]; // agesForNames = null.
                               // Экземпляр словаря не создан.
```

#### LINQ

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
var people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(null);
var names = from p in people select p.Name;
string firstName = names.First(); // Исключение бросается здесь, хотя создаётся
                                  // строкой выше. p = null, потому что
                                  // первый добавленный элемент = null.
```

#### События

```
public class Demo
{
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;

    protected virtual void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {        
        StateChanged(this, e); // Здесь бросится исключение, если на
                               // событие StateChanged никто не подписался
    }
}
```

#### Неудачное именование переменных

Если бы в коде ниже у локальных переменных и полей были разные имена, вы бы обнаружили, что поле не было инициализировано:

```
public class Form1 {
    private Customer customer;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "John";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show(customer.Name);
    }
}
```

Можно избежать проблемы, если использовать префикс для полей:

```
private Customer _customer;
```

#### Цикл жизни страницы ASP.NET

```
public partial class Issues_Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected TestIssue myIssue;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Выполняется только на первой загрузке, но не когда нажата кнопка
            myIssue = new TestIssue(); 
        }
    }
    
    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myIssue.Entry = "NullReferenceException здесь!";
    }
}
```

#### Сессии ASP.NET

```
// Если сессионная переменная "FirstName" ещё не была задана,
// то эта строка бросит NullReferenceException.
string firstName = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
```

#### Пустые вью-модели ASP.NET MVC

Если вы возвращаете пустую модель (или свойство модели) в контроллере, то вью бросит исключение при попытке доступа к ней:

```
// Controller
public class Restaurant:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
         return View();  // Модель не задана.
    }
}

// Razor view 
@foreach (var restaurantSearch in Model.RestaurantSearch)  // Исключение.
{
}
```

---

## Способы избежать

#### Явно проверять на `null`, пропускать код

Если вы ожидаете, что ссылка в некоторых случаях будет равна `null`, вы можете явно проверить на это значение перед доступом к членам экземпляра:

```
void PrintName(Person p) {
    if (p != null) {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

#### Явно проверять на `null`, использовать значение по умолчанию

Методы могут возвращать `null`, например, если не найден требуемый экземпляр. В этом случае вы можете вернуть значение по умолчанию:

```
string GetCategory(Book b) {
    if (b == null)
        return "Unknown";
    return b.Category;
}
```

#### Явно проверять на `null`, выбрасывать своё исключение

Вы также можете бросать своё исключение, чтобы позже его поймать:

```
string GetCategory(string bookTitle) {
    var book = library.FindBook(bookTitle);  // Может вернуть null
    if (book == null)
        throw new BookNotFoundException(bookTitle);  // Ваше исключение
    return book.Category;
}
```

#### Использовать `Debug.Assert` для проверки на `null` для обнаружения ошибки до бросания исключения

Если во время разработки вы знаете, что метод может, но вообще-то не должен возвращать `null`, вы можете воспользоваться `Debug.Assert` для быстрого обнаружения ошибки:

```
string GetTitle(int knownBookID) {
    // Вы знаете, что метод не должен возвращать null
    var book = library.GetBook(knownBookID);  

    // Исключение будет выброшено сейчас, а не в конце метода.
    Debug.Assert(book != null, "Library didn't return a book for known book ID.");

    // Остальной код...

    return book.Title; // Не выбросит NullReferenceException в режиме отладки.
}
```

Однако эта проверка не будет работать в релизной сборке, и вы снова получите `NullReferenceException`, если `book == null`.

#### Использовать `GetValueOrDefault()` для Nullable типов

```
DateTime? appointment = null;
Console.WriteLine(appointment.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now));
// Отобразит значение по умолчанию, потому что appointment = null.

appointment = new DateTime(2022, 10, 20);
Console.WriteLine(appointment.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now));
// Отобразит дату, а не значение по умолчанию.
```

#### Использовать оператор `??` (C#) или `If()` (VB)

Краткая запись для задания значения по умолчанию:

```
IService CreateService(ILogger log, Int32? frobPowerLevel)
{
    var serviceImpl = new MyService(log ?? NullLog.Instance);
    serviceImpl.FrobPowerLevel = frobPowerLevel ?? 5;
}
```

#### Использовать операторы `?.` и `?[` (C# 6+, VB.NET 14+):

Это оператор безопасного доступа к членам, также известный как оператор Элвиса за специфическую форму. Если выражение слева от оператора равно `null`, то правая часть игнорируется, и результатом считается `null`. Например:

```
var title = person.Title.ToUpper();
```

Если свойство `Title` равно `null`, то будет брошено исключение, потому что это попытка вызвать метод `ToUpper` на значении, равном `null`. В C# 5 и ниже можно добавить проверку:

```
var title = person.Title == null ? null : person.Title.ToUpper();
```

Теперь вместо бросания исключения переменной `title` будет присвоено `null`. В C# 6 был добавлен более короткий синтаксис:

```
var title = person.Title?.ToUpper();
```

Разумеется, если переменная `person` может быть равна `null`, то надо проверять и её. Также можно использовать операторы `?.` и `??` вместе, чтобы предоставить значение по умолчанию:

```
// обычная проверка на null
int titleLength = 0;
if (title != null)
    titleLength = title.Length;

// совмещаем операторы `?.` и `??`
int titleLength = title?.Length ?? 0;
```

Если любой член в цепочке может быть `null`, то можно полностью обезопасить себя (хотя, конечно, архитектуру стоит поставить под сомнение):

```
int firstCustomerOrderCount = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count() ?? 0;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в рекомендациях по предотвращению не хватает вот чего: в большинстве случаев семантика полей — non-nullable. В таких случаях NRE означает ошибку в логике программы: что-то недоинициализировано, объект в неправильном состоянии. В этом случае не проверять на `null` и игнорировать ошибку (что прячет баг, а не способствует его исправлению), а исправить код, который должен гарантировать, что `null` не будет.

Comment: @VladD Есть слишком много случаев, когда null — допустимое значение: ленивая инициализация, отсутствие значения "не задано" у типа и т. п. Не везде получается избавиться от null. Так что рекомендация сводится к "старайтесь не использовать null, если это возможно".

Comment: Это да, есть случаи, когда `null` валиден. Тогда, вероятно, первым вопросом должно быть: **валиден** ли `null` в этой точке? Если да, нужна проверка на `null` и адекватная реакция. Если нет, то код верен, а проблема где-то раньше (скорее всего в инициализации).

Comment: c# 6.0 null propagation: `ref1?.ref2?.ref3?.member`

Answer (score 41):

В дополнение к ответу <s>@Discord</s> <s>@Squidward</s> <s>@Athari</s> @Kyubey, давайте рассмотрим вопрос с другой стороны.

Если у вас в процессе выполнения программы случился `NullReferenceException` при доступе по какой-то ссылке, вы должны прежде всего задать себе важный вопрос:

> а имеет ли право эта ссылка иметь значение `null`?

Во многих случаях правильным ответом будет «нет», и значит, исправлять придётся истинную причину ошибки, которая находится в другом месте, и произошла раньше.

Пример: если у вас есть такой класс:

```
class Car
{
    Engine engine;
    Driver driver;
    // ... остаток класса
}
```

Так вот, мотор у машины быть обязан в любом случае, всегда. А вот водитель может в принципе и не сидеть в машине.

Поэтому если вы видите, что обращение к `engine.HorsePower` падает с `NullReferenceException`, реальная проблема состоит в том, что вы забыли инициализировать `engine` в конструкторе. Поэтому и исправлять ошибку нужно не в точке, где падает, а в том месте, которое реально должно бы обеспечить ненулевое значение `engine`.

А вот если вылетает обращение `driver.Age`, то здесь уже проблема прямо в точке обращения, вам необходимо сначала проверить, что `driver != null`, а потом уж обращаться.

Таким образом: если ваша ссылка в точке обращения *не имеет права* иметь значение `null`, то вы не должны дописывать проверку на `null`, тем самым «замазывая» ошибку. Вы должны либо ничего не проверять, а исправить в том месте, где ссылка должна быть инициализирована, либо добавить `Debug.Assert`, либо проверку на `null` и выброс исключения.

Если же ссылка *имеет право* быть `null`-ом, то в этом случае нужно корректно обработать и этот случай.

---

Важное замечание: Если вашу функцию вызывает «внешний мир», вы не должны рассчитывать, что вашей функции передадут хорошие, правильные аргументы. Даже если вы требуете, чтобы объект, который вам передан, не был `null`-ом, всё равно вам могут передать неправильный объект. Поэтому для функций, доступных внешним модулям, необходимо проверять аргументы на `null` сразу же в начале кода, и бросать нужное исключение:

```
public decimal ComputePrice(Car car)
{
    if (car == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("car");
    // ...
```

Где именно проводить границу между «внутренним» и «внешним» миром, вопрос достаточно нетривиальный. Обычно эта граница есть граница модуля (сборки), или даже той её логической части, которая находится в вашей ответственности. Слишком мелкое дробление ведёт к повторению бессмысленного кода (одна часть программы не доверяет другой и постоянно перепроверяет её). Слишком крупное дробление ведёт к необходимости держать в голове миллионы зависимостей («могу я тут передавать `null` или нет?»). Пользуйтесь здравым смыслом и личным опытом.

---

В C# 8 введено, наконец, явное различие между этими двумя случаями. Для тех ссылок, которые могут содержать `null`, введён специальный синтаксис ([в файле должно быть включено `#nullable enable` (или в проекте `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types)):

```
class Car
{
    Engine engine;  // не может быть null
    Driver? driver; // может быть null
    // ... остаток класса
}
```

В этом случае сам компилятор сможет проконтролировать, что вы забыли проинициализировать значение поля `engine`, и выдать вам предупреждение.

Comment: Очень странно приводить информацию о фиче, которая только планируется в новой версии языка, причём в устаревшем виде (согласно текущему плану, будет вводиться "nullable reference type" с модификатором `?`, а не "non-nullable reference type" с модификатором `!`; последний символ будет использоваться для извлечения значения, а не определения переменных).

Comment: @Discord: Последние [design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5033), в которых это упоминалось, упоминают и явный `T!`. Хотя вы правы, поменяю-ка я ссылку.

Comment: @Discord: А в чём проблема с информацией о новой фиче?

Comment: Проблема в том, что фича на очень ранней стадии реализации, поэтому есть большой риск, что ваша информация будет не только бесполезна, как сейчас, но и откровенно неверна, когда фича будет наконец реализована. / Модификатор `!` при объявлении обсуждается только в контексте параметров обобщённых типов. Насколько я понимаю, ваш пример должен иметь вид `Engine engine; Driver? driver;`.

Comment: @Discord: Возможно, актуальность потеряется. Но я буду подправлять ответ, как только новая информация станет известна.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Как там, окончательный синтаксис фичи уже известен?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Спасибо! Хорошие шансы на то, что выйдет именно с `?`, но в последний момент теоретически возможны изменения. Релиз C# 8 будет где-то в первой половине 2019 года, ждём.

Comment: А как можно объяснить такую ситуацию? http://i.piccy.info/i9/0212a95b060462ecfcd2c88464359e9d/1582881583/26672/1364921/nre.png

Comment: @Олег: (1) Многопоточность? (2) А посмотрите, в отладчике, что из `item` и `item.Items` реально равно `null`.

Comment: В том то и загадка, что ни один из элементов не равен `null` http://i.piccy.info/i9/878b560d3459179ec8d96ccb52583b40/1582893314/32542/1364921/nre2.png

Comment: @Олег: Прикольно! А можно stack trace из исключения?

Comment: Вот stack trace: http://i.piccy.info/i9/961eb531213f6a5520f65ae2d8d10658/1582896252/69357/1364921/st.png                 Но я вообще перестаю понимать что либо :( http://i.piccy.info/i9/34d79dbe1215eb77ed54098371c20dc4/1582896371/30502/1364921/st3.png    Выяснил, что ошибка выпадает при использовании определённой темы. Но всё равно я не понимаю почему так? :(

Comment: @Олег: Ну вот вы сами и можете увидеть, что произошло. NullReferenceException произошло глубоко внутри функции `Clear`, так что ни `item`, ни `item.Items` тут не при чём.

Comment: @Олег: У вас произошло изменение выбранного (selected) элемента (скорее всего, выбранный элемент исчез), изменилось какое-то свойство, к которому был привязан триггер.

Comment: Кажеться я понял, в чём дело. Спасибо!   P.S. А всё равно ситуация прикольная :)

Comment: @Олег: Пожалуйста! Да, выглядит реально необычно. Казалось бы, просто `Clear()`, что может пойти не так?