# Использование строки типа String^

Tags: c++-cli

У меня стоит задача зашифровать текст. Я считываю исходный текст из файла и текст шифра из файла. Считываю текст я в переменную типа Sting^, мне нужно сравнить символ из первой строки с каждым символом из стоки шифра.У меня не получается ходить по строке типа String^ с шифром, я пишу cipher[0], cipher[1] и тд. но компилятор выдает мне сообщение об ошибке, как решить эту проблему? Вот код:

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    StreamReader^ fileCipher = gcnew StreamReader("cipher.txt");
    String^ cipher;
    int count = 0;
    while(fileCipher->ReadLine()){
        cipher = fileCipher->ReadLine();
    }
    String^ temp = gcnew String("nbc");
    if(cipher[0] == temp[0])
        MessageBox::Show("Yes!!!");
}
```

При компиляции при нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Comment: Вы не создаёте экземпляр строки `cipher`. В цикле делаете что-то странное. Вы бы хоть поотлаживали код перед тем, как писать здесь вопрос. / Зачем вообще вам C++ CLI? У вас проблемы с базовыми вещами. "Безопаности" таким способом вы не добьётесь, если это вас интересует.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не запускал, но простой построчный просмотр кода показывает, что из всех перечисленных в этом фрагменте переменных значение `null` может иметь только `cipher` (входящие параметры подразумеваем корректными). Она не инициализируется при создании, присваивается только внутри тела `while`, который может и не выполниться ни разу.

Нужны как минимум два исправления: 1. изначально инициализировать строку `cipher` пустой строкой, 2. после чтения проверить, что она не пустая (а то вместо null reference получите out of range)

Comment: Советы помогли в решении проблемы, спасибо!

Comment: Не за что. Кроме того, @Athari прав в следующем: чтобы найти точную строку, в которой произошла ошибка, всегда достаточно запустить отладку/debug. При возникновении исключения отладчик остановится точно в том месте, а дальше можете спокойно смотреть значения всех переменных и выяснять причину.

Comment: @NIA иницилизировать пустой строкой не нужно. `ReadLine()` возвращает указатель на нужную строку. Проверять на `null`, в принципе, хорошая привычка, но при этом нужно понимать, что вообще происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема тут:

```
 while(fileCipher->ReadLine()){
     cipher = fileCipher->ReadLine();
 }
```

При проверке условия цикла Вы считываете строку и не сохраняете её:

`(fileCipher->ReadLine())`.

Но строка не пустая, поэтому выполняется тело цикла: `cipher = fileCipher->ReadLine();` Второй строки уже нет (в тестовом фале всего одна строка), поэтому в `cipher` возвращается `null`.

Дальше обращение к строке `cipher[0]` и вызывает `NullPointerException`.

Перепишите в стиле C (присваивание и проверка в условии цикла)

```
String^ temp = gcnew String("nbc");

while( String^ line = fileCipher->ReadLine() ) {
    if (line->Equals( temp ) ) {
        Console::WriteLine( "Yes!!!" );
    }
}
```