# NullPointerException при использовании StringBuilder

Tags: c#

```
class MinecraftStartInfo
{
    public StringBuilder sb { get; set; }
    public string workingDir { get; set; }

    public void add(String param)
    {
        param = param.Replace("$USERPROFILE$", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
        param = param.Replace("$_WORKINGDIR$", workingDir);
        sb.Append(param);
    }

    public void addWithoutChecks(String param)
    {
        sb.Append(param);
    }

    public void add(int param)
    {
        sb.Append(param + "");
    }

    public string get()
    {
        return sb.ToString().Replace(" , mainclass", ", mainclass").Trim();
    }
}
```

Ошибка на `sb.Append(param)` в `MinecraftStartInfo.add()`:

> NullPointerException / Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: А подумать перед тем как спрашивать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sb = new StringBuilder(); // В конструкторе
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @AGrief: И вы бы сделали `sb` приватным полем, право.

Answer (score -2):

```
class MinecraftStartInfo
{
    private readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private readonly userProfile;

    public MinecraftStartInfo()
    {
        this.userProfile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    }

    public MinecraftStartInfo(string workingDirectory) : this()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
            throw new ArgumentException("workingDirectory");

        this.WorkingDir = workingDirectory;
    }

    public string WorkingDir { get; private set; }

    public void AddWithCheck(string param)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            throw new ArgumentException("param");

        param = param.Replace("$USERPROFILE$", this.userProfile);
        param = param.Replace("$_WORKINGDIR$", this.WorkingDir);

        sb.Append(param);
    }

    public void Add(string param)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            throw new ArgumentException("param");

        sb.Append(param);
    }

    public void Add(int param)
    {
        sb.Append(param);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        this.sb.Replace(" , mainclass", ", mainclass");
        return this.sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```