# Постройка графика из файла .csv на C#

Tags: c#, массивы, график

Я пытаюсь построить график из файла .csv. разделители между значениями  - запятые. Вот так выглядит структура .csv файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделяю значения с помощью Split, и они в считанном массиве даже правильно располагаются (проверяю с помощью вывода в MessageBox.)

Но как только я пытаю считанные значения записывать в массивы (для каждого столбца свой массив) - то сразу вылазит такая ошибка как на картинке

[image]

Вот так выглядит сообщение об ошибке

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in ICSpray.exe Additional information: Ссылка на объект не
>   указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Но основная задача, считать каждые столбцы, и по ним построить графики с помощью MSChart либо ZedGraph.  И вот на этапе записи данных в нужные мне массивы из за этой ошибки остановился.. Как решить задачу?

Вот так выглядит код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace ICSpray
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string[] slist = new string[5] {"0","0","0","0","0"};       
        public string[] data_temp_in;
        public string[] data_temp_out;
        public string[] data_oroshenie_status;
        public string[] data_temptriger_status;
        public string[] data_t_vpsrisk;

        public string data1_read;

        public int i=0;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Cursor Files|*.csv";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Выберите ранее записанный график в формате .csv";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                data1_read =sr.ReadLine();

                data_temp_in[i] = slist[0]; //на этом этапе выскакивает ошибка
                data_temp_out[i] = slist[1];
                data_oroshenie_status[i] = slist[2];
                data_temptriger_status[i] = slist[3];
                data_t_vpsrisk[i] = slist[4];
                i++;

                sr.Close();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы скопировали сообщение об ошибке в текстовом виде.

Comment: А где вы инициализируете `data_temp_in`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: А где вы инициализируете data_temp_in   -   Ну вот, вверху принициализировал же вроде

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ICSpray.exe

Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: @ukr823f: (1) Покажите, где именно вверху проинициализировали. (2) Текст исключения лучше добавить в вопрос.

Comment: 1) Ну вот же- public string[] data_temp_in;

Comment: @ukr823f: Эхм. Вы до этого наверное на C++ писали, да? Наводящий вопрос: а сколько элементов, как вам кажется, в массиве `data_temp_in` после такой инициализации?

Comment: @Discord: Вроде бы именно такого случая (неинициализированный массив) в вашем мегаответе нету.

Comment: Я понял о чём вы говорите. Но теперь вообще запутался как быть. я новичёк ещё. И вот вроде указал программе что будет массив , а какой он и из скольки элесентов не указал. А как этэ сделать я что то непойму, ведь в разных файлах открываемых мной может быть много элементов, и я немогу создать массив фиксированной длины

Comment: @ukr823f: Окей. Вам нужен как бы массив, но чтобы его длину можно было изменять. То есть, `List<int>`. Посмотрите в ответ, там вам посоветовали то же самое.

Comment: @VladD Массивы там как раз очень даже есть.

Comment: @Discord: Ну, я не нашёл упоминания о том, что `int[] x` даёт `x = null`, в отличие от c/c++, в котором `int x[]` не `nullptr` (если скомпилируется). Для новичков это часто точка непонимания.

Comment: @VladD уже лучше, но считывается только значение из первой строки, а мен нужно весь столбец считать и запихнуть в массив из которого построить график 
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                data1_read =sr.ReadLine();
                string[] slist = data1_read.Split(',');                 data_temp_in.Add(slist[0]);
                foreach (var temp_in in data_temp_in)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(temp_in) + "");
                }

Comment: @Discord: Есть `int[] numbers = null;`, что немного не то из-за явного `null`.

Comment: @ukr823f: Если у вас новая проблема, может, задайте новый вопрос?

Comment: @VladD создал новый вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что все ваши массивы кроме `slist` не инициализированы, поэтому при обращении к ним естественно будет возникать ошибка `NullReferenceException`.

Поскольку кнопка может быть нажата произвольное количество раз, вы заранее не знаете, сколько именно элементов будут содержать массивы `data_temp_in`, `data_temp_out`, `data_oroshenie_status`,  `data_temptriger_status`, `data_t_vpsrisk` и не можете их инициализировать с указанной размерностью. Поэтому вам придется при каждом нажатии кнопки увеличивать размерность массива, что трудоемко и не очень красиво. Чтобы избежать этого рекомендую использовать тип `List<>` вместо массива:

```
 public List<string> data_temp_in=new List<string>(); 
 //...
 data_temp_in.Add(slist[0]);
```