# Этот метод или свойство не может вызываться для значений равных Null

Tags: c#, mysql

Возникает проблема при следующем запросе:

```
protected void ShowContact_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowInd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLString"].ConnectionString);
   
    comm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  persons p LEFT JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id LEFT JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id WHERE p.id = @id LIMIT 1", conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowInd);
    conn.Open();
    
    MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        FIO.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", reader.GetString("lastname"), reader.GetString("firstname"), reader.GetString("middlename"));
        COMPANY.Text = string.Format("{0}", reader.GetString("company"));
        POSITION.Text = string.Format("{0}", reader.GetString("position"));
        BIRTHDAY.Text = reader.GetDateTime("birthdate").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); ;
        TELEPHONES.Text = string.Format("{0}", reader.GetString("phone"));

    }
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как только reader.GetString попадает null,возникает эта проблема. Как мне быть?

Возможно ли на уровне запроса, не брать пустые строки?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @Discord, это вообще не дубликат, у него вызов ToString на значении DbNull, а не на null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить условие `IS NOT NULL` в `SQL`-запрос:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  persons p 
LEFT JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
LEFT JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id 
WHERE p.id = @id AND ph.phone IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

или проверять значение `IsDBNull` в `DbDataReader`:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("phone")))
{
    TELEPHONES.Text = string.Format("{0}", reader.GetString("phone"));
}
```

Comment: При запросе пишет Нет записей.

Comment: А есть у вас в этом запросе записи c заполненный phone?

Comment: Извините. Не совсем понял вопрос

Comment: Ну, в запросе я убрал все строки с незаполненным полем phone. Вы говорить, что теперь записей нет. Вот я и спрашиваю: есть ли у вас в базе записи под такой запрос, где поле phone заполнено?

Comment: Мы можем поговорить в чате?

Comment: Можем. В каком?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29639/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-pavelip).

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в базе данных лежит null.

Зачем вообще тебе этот String.Format? Получай нормальный string так:

```
reader.GetString("phone") as string
```

Comment: А нельзя сразу на уровне запроса пустые строки не брать?

Comment: @shatoidil, можно всё. Но вот как и что ты хочешь получить, тебе придётся разобраться самому.