# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта, C#

Tags: c#, классы

Пытаюсь реализовать агрегацию между классами

Файл Apartmen.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClientNS;

namespace ApartmenNS
{
    class Apartmen
    {
        ...

        Client Person;

        ...

        public void AddApartmen(string name, int passport)
        {
            Person.AddClient(name, passport); // Error
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Файл Client.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using ApartmenNS;

    namespace ClientNS
    {
        class Client
        {
            string name;
            int passport;

            public Client ()
            {
                name = "";
                passport = 0;
            }

            int Passport { get {...}
                           set {...} }

            public void AddClient(string N, int P)
            {
                name = N;
                Passport = P; // костыли, знаю
            }
        }
    }
```

Ошибка возникает во время работы программы в строке помеченной "//Error"

Comment: Очевидно, `Person == null`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/10105)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Член класса

```
Client Person;
```

инициализируется `null`-ссылкой.

Вы можете записать его как

```
Client Person = new Person();
```

Чтобы при создании объекта `Apartmen` данный член этого класса инициализировался ссылкой на конкретный объект класса `Person`

Либо такую инициализацию вы можете включить непосредственно в конструктор класса `Apartmen`.

Мне представляет также, что лучше назвать класс `Apartment` вместо `Apartmen`:)

Comment: А не будет ли этот вариант композицией?

Comment: @Алексей Ягело Да, это композиция или по-иному агрегирование.

Comment: У меня в задании: Между парами классов спроектировать отношения композицию (1) и агрегацию (1).
Тогда раз `Client Person = new Person();` - композиция, то как тогда должна выглядеть агрегация?

Comment: @АлексейЯгело Во многих книгах композиция и агрегация используются взаимозаменяемо. Но вам надо смотреть те определения, которые вам давали. К сожалению я не знаю, какие определения этих терминов вам давали.

Comment: Те что на Википедии [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Агрегирование_%28программирование%29)

Comment: @АлексейЯгело  На самом деле это - игра слов: "Композиция (агрегирование по значению) — более строгий вариант агрегирования".  Кто-то на пустом месте пытается создать новый смысл. Если следовать данному определению, то если вы включите создание объекта Person внутри класса Apartmen, то это будет композиция. А если объект Person будет создан вне объекта Apartmen, а обекту Apartmen будет передана ссылка на созданный объект, то это будет агрегация.:)

Answer (score 1):

вы не инициализируете поле `Person` - и оно не указывает на объект в тот момент, когда вы пытаетесь вызывать `Person.AddClient`

```
class Apartment
{
    Client Person = new Client();

    //...
}
```