# C# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Помогите решить проблему как видно и названия "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" выдает ошибку "logic.Option.WcfNameServise".

Логика классы все создаются от абстрактного `AbstractLogic` в нём определен `public AbstractOptionClass Option { get; protected set; }` и в нем определен `WcfNameServise`, в классах наследниках все данные присвоены как положено. В наследниках потом переопределяю `public new ScreenOption Option { get; protected set; }` одной из реализации.

А, вот из реализации не могу получить данные. Подскажите как лучше сделать в этом случае?

```
private void Logic()
{
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Debug("Запуск логики");

    var flag = true;
    var scr = new ScreenLogic();
    var listLogic = new List<AbstractLogic>();
    listLogic.Add(new ScreenLogic());

    while (flag)
    {

        switch (State)
        {
            case StateType.Stoped:
                flag = false;
                break;
            case StateType.Run:

                foreach (var logic in listLogic)
                {
                    if (UnixTime.Now() >= logic.TimeInterval.NexTime)
                    {   
                        //отравка по wcf на сервер, иначе в буфер
                        if (_countErrWcfConnect == 0 || UnixTime.Now() >= GetNextTimeRetryConnetct())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                using (var client = new CollectionOfStatisticsIServiceClient())
                                {

                                    var sendResult = logic.GetResultToWcf();


                                    //logic.Option.WcfNameServise выдает ошибку
                                    MethodInfo method = client.GetType().GetMethod(logic.Option.WcfNameServise);
                                    client.SendScreen( data );
                                    method.Invoke(client, new object[] { sendResult });
                                }

                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {

                                logger.Error (e, e.Message);
                                throw;
                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //logic.SendToBuffer();
                        }  
                    }
                }

                State = StateType.Stoped; // Debug
                break;
            case StateType.Pause:
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    logger.Debug("Остановка логики");
}
```

**Обновление**

> Посмотрите в отладчике чему равно logic.Option.WcfNameServise и инициализируется ли оно вообще.

При наведение выдает

> logic.Option.WcfNameServise = 'logic.Option.WcfNameServise' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Но она инициируется при создание класса и внутри класса, нормально используется ошибок не выдает. Я думаю, тут проблема в том, что я использую абстракцию логики и в этой логике еще абстракция возвращающего типа Option (казан базовый класс Option) а в реализации я указываю уже наследника. Вот думаю, как лучше сделать.

Comment: Часто такая ошибка возникает, если что-то не инициализировали или инициализировали, но не до конца. Посмотрите в отладчике чему равно `logic.Option.WcfNameServise` и инициализируется ли оно вообще..

Comment: Вам непременно должно помочь это: [_Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?_](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/10105)

Comment: @VladD, а почему не бахнуть как дубликат?

Comment: Это не дубликат, у автора на самом деле ошибка в наследовании.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: тогда подойдёт (частично) этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469788/10105

Comment: @VladD там тоже ничего нет про наследование. Вообще, у нас где-то был вопрос именно про такую ситуацию как у автора - но я его потерял )

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, вижу. Тогда вопрос сам по себе специфичный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка вот тут: `public new ScreenOption Option { get; protected set; }`. Для того, чтобы переопределить свойство в классе-наследнике, надо:

- в базовом классе определить его как `virtual`,
- в производном классе определить его как `override`.

Вы же вместо переопределения свойства создали новое, которое скрывает старое. В итоге у вас *два* разных свойства `Options` - и одно из них, разумеется, остается `null`. Замена скрытия на переопределение решит проблему.

Но конкретно в вашей ситуации я бы рекомендовал вам вообще убрать `Options` из наследника. Зачем оно там нужно? Ведь в базовом классе `protected set` написано не просто так - а для того, чтобы дать к этому свойству доступ наследникам без всяких переопределений.

---

### UPD

Так, вижу, у вас проблема еще и в том, что в классе-наследнике меняется тип класса с параметрами. Эту проблему проще всего решить вот так:

```
public new ScreenOption Option
{
  get { return (ScreenOption)base.Option; }
  protected set { base.Option = value; }
}
```

Такой способ обеспечит правильную типизацию свойства в наследнике - и при этом значения обоих свойств будут всегда совпадать, поскольку храниться они будут в одном и том же месте.

Но если подобного кода станет много - у вас что-то не так с архитектурой. Возможно, сама концепция "контейнеров с опциями" является лишней.

Comment: Спасибо, да я согласен что с архитектурой бардак, но учусь на ошибках, я пишу маленькие поделки для обучения и с каждым разом разом узнаю что то новое.

Да я  WcfNameServise перенес на уровень выше в абстракцию логики, т.к. пересмотрел Option не нужен внешнему миру больше.