# Ошибка в Unity при работе с системой жизней в игре

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Делал систему жизней по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zr7ys5lFakA&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz&index=19) туториалу. В конце(время видео 28.15), когда переносил Main HUD в префаб и другие уровни, возникла ошибка. А именно, на первом уровне всё отлично,но когда переходишь на второй или далее, то выскакивает error и не отображаются жизни (другие жизни, которые сердечки сверху) и очки.

Вид c игры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вид c консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код скрипта LifeManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LifeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int startingLives;
    private int lifeCounter;

    private Text theText;

    public GameObject gameOverScreen;

    public PlayerController player;

    public string mainMenu;

    public float waitAfterGameOver;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        theText = GetComponent<Text> ();

        lifeCounter = startingLives;

        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (lifeCounter < 0) 
        {
            gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
            player.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        theText.text = "x " + lifeCounter;

        if (gameOverScreen.activeSelf) 
        {
            waitAfterGameOver -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (waitAfterGameOver < 0)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(mainMenu);        
        }
    }

    public void GiveLife()
    {
        lifeCounter++;
    }

    public void TakeLife()
    {
        lifeCounter--;
    }
}
```

Код скрипта HealthManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxPlayerHealth;

    public static int playerCurHealth;

    private LevelManeger levelManager;

    private LifeManager lifeSystem; 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;

        levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManeger>();
        lifeSystem = FindObjectOfType<LifeManager>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (playerCurHealth <= 0)
        {  
            playerCurHealth = 0;
            levelManager.RespawnPlayer();
            lifeSystem.TakeLife();
        }

        if (playerCurHealth > maxPlayerHealth)
        {
            playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;
        }

    }

    public static void HurtPlayer(int damageToGive)
    {
        playerCurHealth -= damageToGive;
    }

    public void FullHealth()
    {
        playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;
    }
}
```

Код скрипта HUD:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HUD : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite[] HertSprites;

    public Image HeartUI;

    //private HealthManager helthManager;
    public PlayerController player;//был private

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        //helthManager = FindObjectOfType<HealthManager>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        HeartUI.sprite = HertSprites[HealthManager.playerCurHealth];

    }
```

Пару организационных моментов:

1.Не все части кода могут совпадать с туториалом ибо приходилось вносить изменения.

2.[Мой проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1anljqtcaltv1y0/v0012.rar?dl=0). Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку требуется удалить со второго уровня Canvas и заменить на префаб Main HUD.

3.Если умирать с Гейм-Овером, то через улиток.

Comment: Строчка `HeartUI.sprite = HertSprites[HealthManager.playerCurHealth];`, исключение типа NRE. По коду так не вижу, откуда эти переменные все заполняются, так что советую почитать например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/Что-такое-nullreferenceexception-и-как-мне-исправить-код

Comment: @Monk если не хватает информации,то можете чекнуть проект. Ссылка предоставлена в посте ниже. А за вашу ссылку аригато, на днях почитаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если посмотреть в редакторе на скрипт `HUD`, висящий на объекте `Main Camera`, то можно увидеть, что два свойства не заполнены. Исправление этого упущения избавляет от описанной ошибки.

Comment: Одно свойство должно быть пустым(player), а второе UI видимо слетело при переименовании. Вы мега.