# Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, массивы, datagridview

Пишу программу, по сути нужно ввести данные в первую таблицу и вывести в остальных фамилии людей, интерес которых к увлечению больше 0.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имею вот такой код для этой процедуры:

```
DataGridView[] MyArrayGrid = { dataGridView4, dataGridView2, dataGridView6, dataGridView3, dataGridView5 };

        int A;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "";
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
                if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out A) && A != 0)
                {
                 MyArrayGrid[i].Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value);
                }
```

И в итоге получаю ошибку *Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException"*

Как быть, что исправить? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Судя по всему, дубликат: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/10105)

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value), out A) && A != 0)`

Comment: @Igor
Вот, спасибо! 
Но теперь дальше ошибка уже _"System.IndexOutOfRangeException"_

 `MyArrayGrid[i].Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value);`

Comment: Если в `dataGridView1` больше 5 столбцов, - `MyArrayGrid[i]` вызовет ошибку "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" для `i = 5`.

Comment: @Igor 
Аа, то есть это связано с размером массива таблиц, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @Den4ik Так точно.

Comment: @Igor
Благодарю

Comment: А, Вам надо `MyArrayGrid[i - 2]`

Comment: @Igor
Пробовал так, но все равно не работает. 
Функционально, если добавить 2 лишних датагрида и банально спрятать их на форме

Comment: @Den4ik - ну начинать-то тоже надо не с 1 а с `i = 2;`

Comment: @Igor 
Теперь вообще прекрасно, спасибо! 
Снимаю шляпу перед вашим пониманием языка