# ExecuteReader() и размножение сессии при kill session

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

Задумал такую процедурку в Visual studio 2008, запускается в отдельном потоке:

```
 void Run()
 {
        string oradb = "Data Source=" + Alias.Text + ";" + "User Id=" + Login.Text + ";" + "Password=" + Password.Text + ";";
        foring = 0;
        //---
        OracleCommand cmd=null;
        OracleDataReader dr=null;
        string str;

        var ink = FindWindow(null, "Alert locks");//Получаем дескриптор окна

         do
         {
            try
            {
                conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(id1) d FROM V$LOCK WHERE request > 0";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();  
                str = dr["d"].ToString();
                if ((str != "0") && (foring == 0))
                {
                    SetWindowPos(ink, (IntPtr)HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);//Включает свойство TOPMOST - Дескриптору окну
                    MessageBox(ink, "ATTENTION!!! LOCKS FOUND!!!", "Alert locks message", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_TOPMOST);
                    SetWindowPos(ink, (IntPtr)HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);//Отключает свойство TOPMOST - Дескриптору окну
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                };

            }
            catch (OracleException ex) // catches only Oracle errors
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                   case 03113:
                        MessageBox(ink, "Lost connection to the database.", "Alert locks message", 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox(ink, "Database error: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Alert locks message", 0);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // catches any error not previously caught
            {
                MessageBox(ink, ex.Message.ToString(), "Alert locks message", 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Dispose();
            } 
         } while (foring == 0);
 }
```

Задумал для того, чтобы постоянно мониторился запрос(знаю, что можно написать по-другому, это тестовый вариант). Как только будет результат, выдастся сообщение, после закрытия которого, мониторинг продолжится(остановить его можно только через кнопку на форме, дабы цикл не был бесконечен). Собственно, после проверки, что будет, при убийстве сессии, обнаружил, что после срабатывания исключения и прохода следующих итераций, сессия превращалась в 5 сессий(только сиды разные). Вопрос в том, почему так и как избавиться от этого?

P.s. Знаю про работу провайдера с пулом, и для чего Open и Dispose и как их можно заменить, но так как изучаю недавно, возможно что-то не учел -_-

Comment: Зачем вы делаете ExecuteReader - если вызов [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) намного проще?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, во-первых, давно не кодил, во-вторых, про Oracle Data Provider узнал не так давно, поэтому пробовал пример, указанный самим Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечая на поставленный вопрос, выяснил, что дело было в настройках пула соединений по умолчанию, а точнее в параметрах `Min Pool Size=1 и Incr Pool Size=5`. Таким образом, при убивании одной текущей сессии, при создании новой их количество вырастало на 5. Так как по умолчанию `Min Pool Size=1`, то в пуле всегда поддерживается хотя бы одна сессия. При установке `Min Pool Size=0` автоматических сессий не будет создаваться (в противном случае, даже при очистке пула, в нем автоматически создастся минимальное количество сессий), а при установке `Incr Pool Size=1;` уже будет создаваться не 5 новых сессий, а одна.

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли, что переменные `dr`, `cmd` и `conn` могут оказаться пустыми (null) - и тогда при попытке вызвать Dispose возникнет NRE (советую посмотреть вопрос [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

Вторая проблема - в том, что инициализируются эти переменные всего 1 раз - и если произошла ошибка, то на след. итерации в этой переменной будет лежать значение, которое туда присвоилось на прошлой итерации.

Вам надо

1. перенести объявления либо инициализацию переменных в начало цикла,
2. перед вызовом Dispose проверять переменные на null.

Или же можно переписать код так, чтобы использовать конструкцию using вместо try-finally.

PS надеюсь, поле `foring` у вас объявлено как `volatile`, иначе могут быть проблемы с оптимизацией.

Еще лучше для передачи сигнала на остановку использовать `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Лучше, только ввели CancellationToken в 4-ом фреймворке, а в 2008 только 3.5