# Исправить ошибку Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

Есть метод

```
private void dataGuests_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    string SqlQuery = "select * from guests ORDER BY id DESC;";
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, connStr);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();               
        adapter.Update(DS, "guests");
        //adapter.Fill(DS, "LoadDataBinding");
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения ругается на:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   System.Data.dll.
>   Дополнительные сведения: Операции Update не удалось найти
>   TableMapping["guests"] или DataTable "guests".

Прочитал [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), но конструктор выбирает все данные из этой же таблицы и заливает их в Grid. Причём корректно.
Проверил в таблице PRIMARY KEY - в наличии.

Прошу направить заблудшего странника

Comment: Почитайте http://professorweb.ru/my/ADO_NET/base/level2/2_4.php , по опыту скажу - на простые вопросы сообщество RU SO перестало отвечать, к сожалению (хотя главная цель любого SO - помощь людям), постарайтесь разобраться своими силами.

Comment: Вы создали пустой датасет. Естественно, в нём нет таблицы `guests`.

Comment: вы создали пустую таблицу DataSet, но ничего в неё не положили

Answer (score -1):

Не

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, connStr);
```

а

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn);
```