# помогите с ошибкой NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
private void updateCosts() // Метод для обновления текста с ценами
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shopItems.Count; i++) // Цикл выполняется, пока переменная i < кол-ва товаров
        {
            if (shopItems[i].itsBonus) // Если товар является бонусом, то:
            {
                float cost = shopItems[i].cost * shopItems[shopItems[i].itemIndex].bonusCounter; // Рассчитываем цену в зависимости от кол-ва рабочих (к примеру)
                shopItemsText[i].text = shopItems[i].name + "\n"  + conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(cost, false, false) + "$"; // Обновляем текст кнопки с рассчитанной ценой
            }
            else shopItemsText[i].text = shopItems[i].name + "\n"  + conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(shopItems[i].cost , false, false) + "$"; // Иначе если товар не является бонусом, то обновляем текст кнопки с обычной ценой
        }
    }
```

unity выдает ошибку

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Game.updateCosts () (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:119) Game.Start
>   () (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:65)

и выделяет строчку в скрипте :

```
  else shopItemsText[i].text = shopItems[i].name + "\n"  + conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(shopItems[i].cost , false, false) + "$"; // Иначе если товар не является бонусом, то обновляем текст кнопки с обычной ценой
```

Comment: Покажи класс из которого состоит "shopItems". Возможно поле "conveterscore" не инициализировано. Это можно отладить и самому.

Comment: или `shopItemsText[i]`

Comment: Вам, судя по всему, сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/10105

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать отладку и посмотреть, что содержится shopItems[i] ? Возможно, элемент массива содержит null, т.е. не инициализирован.

Comment: или одно из свойств элемента, например `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Текст, отвечающий за отображение денег")]
    public Text scoreText;
    [Header("Магазин")]
    public List<Item> shopItems = new List<Item>();
    [Header("Текст на кнопках товаров")]
    public Text[] shopItemsText;
    [Header("Кнопки товаров")]
    public Button[] shopBttns;
    [Header("Панелька магазина")]
    public GameObject shopPan;
    [Header("Выход магазина")]
    public GameObject exitshopPan;

    private float score; //Игровая валюта
    private float scoreIncrease = 1; //Бонус при клике
    private Save sv = new Save ();

    [Header("Вывод текста на экран")]
    public Text MyTestLabel;


    bool _escBePressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SV"))
        {


            float totalBonusPS = 0 ;
            sv = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("SV"));
            score = sv.score;
            for (int i = 0; i < shopItems.Count; i++)
            {

                shopItems[i].levelOfItem = sv.levelOfItem[i];
                shopItems[i].bonusCounter = sv.bonusCounter[i];
                if (shopItems[i].needCostMultiplier) shopItems[i].cost *= (int)Mathf.Pow(shopItems[i].costMultiplier, shopItems[i].levelOfItem);
                if (shopItems[i].bonusIncrease != 0) scoreIncrease += (int)Mathf.Pow(shopItems[i].bonusIncrease, shopItems[i].levelOfItem);

                    totalBonusPS += shopItems [i].bonusPerSec * shopItems [i].bonusCounter;
            }
            DateTime dt = new DateTime (sv.date[0],sv.date[1],sv.date[2],sv.date[3],sv.date[4],sv.date[5]); 
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
            float offlineBonus = (float)ts.TotalSeconds * totalBonusPS; 
            score += offlineBonus ; 
            print("Вы отсутствовали: " + ts.Days + "Д. " + ts.Hours + "Ч. " + ts.Minutes + "М. " + ts.Seconds + "S.");
            print ("Вы заработали " + offlineBonus + "$");
            MyTestLabel.text = ("В ваше  отсутствие заработалось " + offlineBonus + "$");
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {

        updateCosts(); //Обновить текст с ценами
        StartCoroutine(BonusPerSec()); //Запустить просчёт бонуса в секунду

    }

    private void Update()
    {

        scoreText.text = conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(score , false ,false) +"$"  ;//Отображаем деньги

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            _escBePressed = !_escBePressed;
        }
    }

    public void BuyBttn(int index) //Метод при нажатии на кнопку покупки товара (индекс товара)
    {

        float cost = shopItems[index].cost * shopItems[shopItems[index].itemIndex].bonusCounter; //Рассчитываем цену в зависимости от кол-ва рабочих (к примеру)

        if (shopItems[index].itsBonus && score >= cost) //Если товар нажатой кнопки - это бонус, и денег >= цены(е)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize("1323575", false);

            StartCoroutine(ShowAdWhenReady());

            if (cost > 0) // Если цена больше чем 0, то:
            {
                score -= cost; // Вычитаем цену из денег
                StartCoroutine(BonusTimer(shopItems[index].timeOfBonus, index)); //Запускаем бонусный таймер
            }
            else print("Нечего улучшать то!"); // Иначе выводим в консоль текст.
        }
        else if (score >= shopItems[index].cost) // Иначе, если товар нажатой кнопки - это не бонус, и денег >= цена
        {
            if (shopItems[index].itsItemPerSec) shopItems[index].bonusCounter++; // Если нанимаем рабочего (к примеру), то прибавляем кол-во рабочих
            else scoreIncrease += shopItems[index].bonusIncrease; // Иначе бонусу при клике добавляем бонус товара
            score -= shopItems[index].cost; // Вычитаем цену из денег
            if (shopItems[index].needCostMultiplier) shopItems[index].cost *= shopItems[index].costMultiplier; // Если товару нужно умножить цену, то умножаем на множитель
            shopItems[index].levelOfItem++; // Поднимаем уровень предмета на 1
        }
        else print("Не хватает денег!"); // Иначе если 2 проверки равны false, то выводим в консоль текст.
        updateCosts(); //Обновить текст с ценами
    }
    private void updateCosts() // Метод для обновления текста с ценами
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shopItems.Count; i++) // Цикл выполняется, пока переменная i < кол-ва товаров
        {
            if (shopItems[i].itsBonus) // Если товар является бонусом, то:
            {
                float cost = shopItems[i].cost * shopItems[shopItems[i].itemIndex].bonusCounter; // Рассчитываем цену в зависимости от кол-ва рабочих (к примеру)
                shopItemsText[i].text = shopItems[i].name + "\n"  + conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(cost, false, false) + "$"; // Обновляем текст кнопки с рассчитанной ценой
            }
            else shopItemsText[i].text = shopItems[i].name + "\n"  + conveterscore.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(shopItems[i].cost , false, false) + "$"; // Иначе если товар не является бонусом, то обновляем текст кнопки с обычной ценой
        }
    }
```