# Unity3D/C# + MSSQL: ошибка открытия соединения

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity3d, windows-10

Моя программа на Unity3D работает с MSSQL-базой. ОС - Windows 10. Когда клиентская программа запускалась в нашей сетке и коннектилась к серверному компу в нашей сетке, всё было ок. В сетке заказчика при попытке открытия соединения с базой выскакивает вот такой exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.Connect
>   (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80.Connect
>   (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0

Строка подключения к БД:

```
"Server=192.168.xxx.xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;
Database=DatabaseName;
User ID=User;
Password=password"
```

Строка, на которой выскакивает исключение:

```
sqlConnection.Open();
```

При этом если установить клиентское Unity3D-приложение на серверный компьютер заказчика, где установлена MSSQL-база, то всё работает, как надо. Другие приложения, установленные на клиентском компьютере заказчика (в т.ч. приложения и на C#, и на Unity3D) нормально работают с базой на серверном компе.

Мне кажется, дело или в сетевых настройках (но админ 10 раз проверил все настройки и отключил файрвол), или в том, что на клиентском компе заказчика отсутствует какой-то софт и приложение пытается обратиться к dll, который есть на клиентском компе в нашей сетке и на серверном компе заказчика, но отсутствующему на клиентском компе в сетке заказчика.

Это мой первый опыт работы с MSSQL. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и может подсказать, в каких направлениях стоит двигаться, чтобы исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Общее описание ошибки [NullReferenceException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Отсюда ([Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlclient/))

> By default, SQL Server 2005 Express has TCP/IP disabled. So, you have
>   to go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable TCP/IP for each
>   instance you wish to connect via TCP/IP. But, you also must make sure
>   the TCP/IP Protocol is one of the allowed client protocols. You may
>   need to make sure your firewall allows mono.exe to do networking. And
>   allow the SQL Server Monitor UDP Port 1434 in your firewall. If this
>   UDP port is not enabled, then SqlClient running on Linux will not be
>   able to get the TCP port to connect to based on the instance name
>   SQLEXPRESS. SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration - Protocols for -
>   SQLEXPRESS - enable TCP/IP. And SQL Server Native Client - Client
>   Protocols - enable TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать логин от учётной записи Windows то Mono почему-то не хочет подключаться, ни с паролем ни с аутентификацией Windows (совмещенное).

Мне помогло создание учётной записи на сервере через Management Studio:

1. Заходим в Management Studio и подключаемся к SQL серверу;
2. Переходим в Безопасность - ПКМ по "Имена входа" - "Создать имя входа". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В поле «Имя входа» указать логин.
4. Затем выбрать "Проверка подлинности SQL Server" и указать любой пароль.
5. Оставить включенной опцию «Требовать использование политики паролей». Остальные галочки убрать что бы не было гемора.
6. В низу выберать базу данных по умолчанию. Именно эта база будет открываться после подключения пользователя к серверу. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Переходим в "Сопоставление пользователей".В верхнем списке отметить таблицы, с которыми можно будет работать при помощи этой учётной записи. В нижнем списке выбрать права. Обычно достаточно "**db_owner**" и "**public**". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка подключения такая:
string connectionString = `"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=DBTP;UserID=admin;Password=admin;";`