# Реализовать поиск по списку

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста реализовать поиск по списку. Две недели мучаюсь!

```
public class TabFragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARGS_EXAMPLE = "";
    private String example_data;

    final String ATRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE = "image";
    final String ATRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";

    private ListView listView;

    private String[] names = {
            "А",
            "Б",
            "В",
            "Г",
            "Д"};

    private int[] images = {
            R.mipmap.a,
            R.mipmap.b,
            R.mipmap.c,
            R.mipmap.d,
            R.mipmap.e};

    public TabFragmentOne() {

    }

    private SearchView searchView;

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

    public static TabFragmentOne newInstance(String example_argument) {
        TabFragmentOne tabFragmentOne = new TabFragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARGS_EXAMPLE, example_argument);
        tabFragmentOne.setArguments(args);
        return tabFragmentOne;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        example_data = getArguments().getString(ARGS_EXAMPLE);
        Log.i("Fragment create with", example_data);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        searchView = (SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(magas.length);
        Map<String, Object> map;

        String[] from = {ATRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE};
        int[] to = {R.id.tvMainLv, R.id.imgMainLv};

        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), data, R.layout.listview_main_for_tab, from, to);

        for (int i = 0; i < magas.length; i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(ATRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, magas[i]);
            map.put(ATRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, images[i]);
            data.add(map);
        }

        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                simpleAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "А", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Б", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "В", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Г", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return view;

    }


}
```

```
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:712)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:835)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:5966)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:50)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-27 11:37:00.935 3546-3546/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413042/178988 - язык не тот, но идея та же

Comment: SimpleAdapter - что это за класс? Если ваш - давайте код

Comment: Куда скидывать код? я просто новичок)

Comment: вот мой код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750110/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: Кто-нибудь может помочь!

Answer (score 0):

У Вас поле count не инициализируется, поэтому вылетает NPE при попытке его получить. Довольно распространённая ошибка при использовании getter-ов.

В SimpleAdapter есть счётчик, который считает, сколько элементов Вы передали в data в конструктор SimpleAdapter. Вы передали пустой List, стало быть, data.size() = 0, и count должен быть 0, но он почему-то null, отсюда NPE.

Я java-разработчик, в студию залезть сейчас не могу, но Вы можете начинать копать в эту сторону, подебажить, а также, попытаться наполнить чем-то data.

Comment: как мне устранить эту ошибку? Что нужно создать, дописать?

Comment: Для этого нужно предусмотреть инициализацию count раньше, чем Вы вызываете геттер. Если вылетает NPE - значит, Вы что-то неправильно спроектировали в своём приложении. Что такое count и что она означает?

Comment: Судя по названию, это какой-то счётчик. Сделайте при объявлении поля: count = 0; Или в пустом конструкторе инициализируйте: this.count = 0; и во всех непустых.

Comment: у меня в коде нет геттеров) то что я загр. здесь, это весь мой код.

Comment: Я добавил комментарий в свой ответ выше.

Comment: ничего не помогает)