# Как программно изменить title другого окна? И как программно менять xaml элементы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как программно изменить title другого xaml окна? Из xaml страницы? Пробовал так - `MainMenu.Title = "new title";`(MainMenu объявил), но выбивает ошибку -

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

И как программно менять xaml элементы? Например колонки в dataGrid, не только их имя но и количество и т.д.?

Comment: `MainMenu объявил` - как?

Comment: private MainMenu MainMenu; немного сомневаюсь правильно или нет, но VS не подчёркивает.

Comment: Ну а экземпляр-то вы как создаете?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: MainWindow = new MainWindow(); так. Неправильно?

Comment: Теперь нет ошибки, но и title не меняется.

Comment: Хорошо. Вы создаете новый экземпляр теперь. Задайте имя окну прямо в разметке: `Name="myWindow"`, а потом в коде обращайтесь к нему по этому имени: `myWindow.Title = "new title";`

Comment: Добавил имя MainWIn. Если просто сделаю так -  MainWin.Title = "new title"; то - the name 'MainWin' does not exist in the current context. А если так - MainWindow.MainWin.Title = "new title";, то ничего не меняется.

Comment: Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы хотите поменять заголовок другого окна? Вы должны как-то получить ссылку на него.

Comment: Можно узнать что именно вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я хочу менять заголовок окна из другой страницы. Нажимаю я на кнопку из второй страницы(которая находится во frame в первом окне) и во frame загружается другая страница и заголовок окна меняется. Заголовок один, а окна три.

Comment: А как получить ссылку?

Comment: Передать ее заинтересованному лицу в параметре конструктора или через свойство

Comment: Можно по подробнее? Или как гуглить такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так: у меня есть `MainWindow` с кнопкой и `Window1` с кнопкой, в `Window1` я добавляю параметр в конструктор и поле для хранения ссылки, по нажатию кнопки теперь я могу обратиться по ссылке к этому окну, на которое получена ссылка:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Window targetWindow;

    public Window1(Window targetWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.targetWindow = targetWindow;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        targetWindow.Title = "New title!";
    }
}
```

Теперь, при создании окна `Window1` необходимо передать ему ссылку на окно, в котором нужно менять свойство, обработчик клика по кнопке `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new Window1(this);
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как выглядит "параметр в конструктор и поле для хранения ссылки"?

Comment: Ну в ответе это же всё есть: `public Window1(Window targetWindow)` - это конструктор с параметром, `Window targetWindow;` - это поле

Comment: Заработало. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Теперь я из третьего окна меню title таким образом - `MainWindow MainWin = new MainWindow();
            DefaultTitle DefTitle = new DefaultTitle();
            DefTitle.SetDefaultTitle(MainWin);
            MessageBox.Show(MainWin.Title);`
Класс defaulTitle - `public void SetDefaultTitle(Window MainWin)
        {
            MainWin.Title = "Главное меню2";
        }`
MessageBox выводит главное меню2, а заголовок не меняется. Почему?

Comment: Потому что вы создаете новое окно и меняете заголовок у него, а вам нужно поменять заголовок у существующего окна