# Как менять свойства xaml элементов из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Привет. Есть dataGridview -

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridXAML" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="441" Margin="10,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1044">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID сотрудника"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Отчество" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Каким образом можно поменять через код количество колонок, их имя и другие параметры?

Из другой xaml страницы.

Comment: Можно узнать что вы хотите получить?

Comment: обращаться к элементам управления можно по имени, в вашем случае это `DataGridXAML`

Comment: Обратится к элементу другой xaml страницы.

Comment: @xomem, почитайте это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764737/218063

Comment: Прочитал. Сделал. Работает. Спасибо.

Comment: у меня есть подозрения что вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: могу поинтересоваться какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Почему? Я же написал, что получилось. Ну а вообще, будут разные виды SQL запросов, и в зависимости от запроса dataGrid должна меняться. Подстраиваться под таблицу.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Вот есть разные таблицы. Отличающиеся количеством полей(3 и 5). При запросе с первой нужно удалить два(если ранние был вызван запрос со второй) и наоборот, при вызове с последней добавлять. Но ведь это не красиво, учитывая что таких таблиц может быть не две а пять. Создавать пять одинаковы страниц отличающихся только запросами не вариант. Как лучше поступить?

Comment: уже понятнее, но не полностью. Я бы создал для каждой таблицы свое описание столбцов с возможностью менять их видимость и уже в зависимости от запроса показывал бы тот или иной вариант. Если подобный способ вам кажется слишком многословным, то можно положиться на автогенерацию столбцов и просто менять источник данных.

Comment: @FoggyFinder . Спасибо.

Comment: @FoggyFinder а как  сделать автогенерацию полей? Добавил такие параметры к DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" и в классе SimpleQueryResult.SQRDataGridXAML.ItemsSource = test; . Но dataGrid пуст и ошибок нет.

Comment: есть возможность показать больше кода например через gist ? по такому отрывку можно только строить предположения из-за чего так происходит

Comment: @FoggyFinder https://gist.github.com/xomem/2e993c79cf5ff344c0ba8ed68dc84090 вот

Comment: что-то тут не то, вы задаете `string` в качестве `ItemsSource`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder да. Понял что это не правильно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder  А как нужно?

Comment: вы не возражаете перейти в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Например:

```
DataGridXAML.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        Header="Дед Мороз",
        Width="200"
    });
```

Чтобы поменять:

```
DataGridXAML.Columns[0].Header="Снегурочка";
```

Документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

Если вам нужен доступ из другой страницы, сделайте эту страницу доступной другой странице любым путём, и получайте доступ через `yourPage.DataGridXAML.Columns...`.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что нужно поменять этот же элемент из другой XAML страницы. Как получить доступ к другой страницы?

Comment: А как менять данные? Не добавлять.

Comment: @xomem: Получите объект другой страницы, возьмите у него `DataGridXAML`, дальше точно так же.

Comment: @xomem: Чтобы менять, нужно просто `DataGridXAML.Columns[0].Header="Снегурочка"`

Comment: Спасибо. А есть что то типа DataGridXAML.Columns[Where name == `name`].Header="Снегурочка". Чтобы каждой колонке добавить идентификатор и по нему уже искать?

Comment: @xomem, заведите словарь и храните ссылки на столбцы в нем

Comment: @Андрей-nop json файл в смысле?

Comment: @xomem, я имею ввиду коллекцию типа `Dictionary<string, ...>` причем тут json и файл...

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю что это такое.

Comment: @xomem: Ну можно просто `DataGridXAML.Columns.Where(c => c.Header == "Дед Мороз"]).Single().Header="Снегурочка"`, например.

Comment: ещё. В xaml разметке можно задать ширину колонке - width = "*". Это растянет её на всё поле. А как задать такую ширину всем колонкам через код? SQRDataGridXAML.ColumnWidth = ?;

Comment: @xomem: `new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)`?

Comment: @VladD большое спасибо.