# Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Client.Socket" требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную ошибку?

**`Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Client.Socket" требуется ссылка на объект`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TLS.Crypto.Tls;
using TLS.Network;

namespace TLS.List
{
    internal class Client
    {
        public Socket Socket { get; set; }
        internal static Int64 TLSMessageCounter = 1;
        internal static Crypto Crypto = new Crypto();

        internal static void Send(string Message)
        {
            byte[] BytesMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
            byte[] HMAC = new HMACSHA1(Crypto.ServerWriteMac).ComputeHash(Tools.HexToBytes(TLSMessageCounter.ToString("X16")+ "170301" + BytesMessage.Length.ToString("X4") + TLS.Network.Process.Bit(BytesMessage)));

            byte[] BytesWithHMAC = Tools.Concat(BytesMessage, HMAC);
            int index = BytesWithHMAC.Length + 20;

            int modulo = (BytesWithHMAC.Length + 1) % 16;
            byte paddingLength = (byte)(16 - modulo);
            BytesWithHMAC = Tools.Concat(BytesWithHMAC, new byte[] { paddingLength });

            for (int i = 0; i < paddingLength; i++) BytesWithHMAC = Tools.Concat(BytesWithHMAC, new byte[] { paddingLength });
            byte[] AesEncrypted = AesTool.Encrypt(BytesWithHMAC, Client.Crypto.ServerWriteKey, Client.Crypto.ServerWriteIV, PaddingMode.None);

            Socket.Send(Tools.HexToBytes("170301" + (AesEncrypted.Length).ToString("X4") + Process.Bit(AesEncrypted)));
            Array.Copy(AesEncrypted, AesEncrypted.Length - 16, Client.Crypto.ClientWriteIV, 0, 16);
            TLSMessageCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать нестатическое свойство в статическом контексте

Comment: Чтобы решить данную проблему достаточно не использовать экземплярные поля в статическом контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь из статического метода получить доступ к нестатическому члену, естественно это не работает. Уберите `static` из заголовка метода `Send`

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что ваше решение просто породит для автора другую проблему (NPE)

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос, может автор не привел кусок кода с конструктором, в котором создается экземпляр `Socket`

Comment: Я просто для ясности уточнил, что вы решите одну проблему, но код без создания сокета все равно не заработает.

Comment: @tym32167, для NRE есть [эталонный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/186999)

Comment: Только не NPE, а **NRE** ;)

Comment: @Grundy я не пытаюсь дать второй ответ на это, я просто написал для автора вопроса, что когда он уберет `static`, у него вылетит вторая проблема, есть он не создает экзепляр сокета (имхо это можно было бы и в ответе упомянуть) - это все, что я хотел, больше ничего не хотел :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да да, ну вы поняли :)