# При проверке условия @if(Model.ImageData == null) выходит ошибка System.NullReferenceExecption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Пытаюсь кастомизировать регистрацию Identity 2, чтобы у пользователя еще были поля возраст, о себе, и самое главное фото. Загрузку фото взял отсюда [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level2/2_13.php). Ошибка в @if (Model.ImageData == null) NullReference,
Базу на поля обновлял в Обозревателе серверов и IdentityModels.cs [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://prntscr.com/ikethh), AccountViewModels.cs
Проблема в том, что я как раз таки проверяю на это исключение, а оно без проверки выдает ошибку... если объект равен null, то "Картинки нет", ошибка до проверки

Comment: так может Model равно null? вы модель точно передаете?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Исключение говорит о том, что `Model` равно `null`, a не `Model.ImageData`.

Comment: когда комментирую условие все показывается, другие поля показываются