# Передача данных из класса в textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, делегаты

Есть программа которая сравнивает строки по дате. Необходимо чтобы в textBox отображался процесс работы программы, а именно выводились найденные строки. Нашел способ вывода через делегаты. Сделал следующим образом:

В классе Program объявил

```
public static readonly GpsEditor MEditor;
```

В классе формы добавил:

```
   public delegate void TextBoxDelegate(string text);
   public void MyTextBox(string input)
   {
       if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
       {
           textBox1.Invoke(new TextBoxDelegate(MyTextBox), new object[] {input + "\n"});
       }
       else
       {
           textBox1.Text += input + "\n";
       }
   }
```

А в классе в котором находятся строки прописал так:

```
Program.MEditor.MyTextBox(Info.View);
```

В результате получаю:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Если в классе объявлю объект формы исключение не выйдет, но текстбокс так и не обновляется.
Rак правильно передавать данные из класса в textBox?

Comment: Пример по которому писал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703698/invokedelegate

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    public void MyTextBox(string input)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new TextBoxDelegate(MyTextBox), new object[] { input });
            return;
        }

        textBox1.Text += input + "\n";
    }
```

Но лучше конечно выводить многострочный текст в RichTextBox:

```
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.TextLength;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText((this.richTextBox1.TextLength > 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + input);
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = this.richTextBox1.ForeColor;
        this.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Чтобы обратиться к форме, нужно её вызвать из списка открытых форм по её имени.

```
MEditor form = (MEditor) Application.OpenForms["MEditor"];
if (form != null)
    form.MyTextBox(Info.View);
```

Напрямую при обращении к форме вы всегда получите ошибку!

Comment: не помогло, все осталось точно также

Comment: Обновил ответ. Проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо! это решило мою проблему