# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта (System.Configuration)

Tags: c#

Ошибка

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>      в FastFoodDemo.Program.GetConnection() в C:\Users\User\Desktop\FastFoodDemo\FastFoodDemo\Program.cs:строка 36

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace FastFoodDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }

        public static int admin = 0;
        public static string server = "null";

        public static MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect_admin"].ConnectionString;
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

app.config

```html
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connect_admin" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=123" 
       providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Как быть господа, подскажите пожалуйста)
При том, что при запуске программы из VS 2017 - она работает.  Но как только запускают готовый *.exe, вылетает вот такое :(

Comment: А в той же папке, где лежит "готовый" exe, присутствует файл *.exe.config? И в нем написано тоже, что и в вашем примере?

Comment: Сборка идёт через ILMerge. Рядом только pdb файл.

Comment: Ну так вот и ответ, положите конфиг рядом с исполняемым файлом, назвав его в формате `exename.exe.config`

Comment: Зачем? Программа и без нее прекрасно работала. Просто меняю коннект к базе и возникла эта проблема.

Comment: Ничего не понял. У вас падает приложение на `ConnectionStrings["connect_admin"]` так как этой секции нет в конфигурационном файле, так как самого конфигурационного файла нет. Скомпилируйте приложение и откройте папку `bin` там будет лежать ваш исполняемый файл и рядом конфигурационный файл, поэтому у вас все работает "из студии". Так же вам нужно поступить с вашим выходным файлом после ILMerge, положить рядом этот конфигурационный файл с именем в формате, который я написал комментарием выше.

Comment: Тьфу... Я дурак) Все верно спасибо, но тогда мои проблемы увеличиваются, т.к. это я делал в целях защиты логина и пароля к базе. Как теперь быть( Если файл конфигурации всегда будет рядом

Comment: Не хранить пароль в открытом виде, естественно. Если вам будет легче, то ILMerge вам тоже вряд-ли поможет. Пересмотрите архитектуру приложения в плане аутентификации в базе данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код падает c [`NullReferenceException`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), так как `ConnectionStrings["connect_admin"]` возвращает `null` в следствии того, что конфигурационный файл отсутствует в директории поиска.

---

Имя [конфигурационного файла](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files) в выходной директории всегда должно соответствовать формату `имя_исполняемого_файла.расширение.config` и находится в той же директории, что и этот исполняемый файл. Например, исполняемому файлу `program.exe` должен соответствовать конфигурационный файл `program.exe.config`