# Не могу понять как решить ошибку в классах

Tags: c#, классы

[image: Ошибка]

Основной код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReadProductsArray();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public static int n { get; private set; }

public static Product[] products = new Product[n];
public static Currency[] cur = new Currency[n];

public static Product[] Products { set; get; }

public static void ReadProductsArray()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість товарів:");
    if (!byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out byte n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");

    }

        products = new Product[n];
        cur = new Currency[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            products[i] = new Product();

            Console.WriteLine($"----------------{i}---------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть ім'я:");
            products[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть ціну:");
            products[i].Price = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість:");
            products[i].Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть виробника:");
            products[i].Producer = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть вагу:");
            products[i].Weight = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());



        }

}
```

Код класса где происходит ошибка:

```
 class Currency
    {
        protected  string name;
        protected  float exRate;

        public Currency()
        {
            name = "UAH";
            exRate = 28;
        }
        public Currency(string n, float e)
        {
            name = n;
            exRate = e;
        }
        public Currency(string na)
        {
            name = na;
        }
     public Currency(Currency previous)
        {
            name = previous.name;
            exRate = previous.exRate;
            }

        public float GetExRate()
        {
            return exRate;
        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
        public float ExRate
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: У вас уже вроде были подобные вопросы и вы так и не поняли как справляться с данной ошибкой. По этому голосую за закрытие как дубликат.

Comment: что-то не то в качестве *основного кода* показываете, там нигде не вызывается ваш порождающий ошибку конструктор копирования `Currency(Currency previous)`, как и любой другой конструктор этого класса.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе нет кода, создающего объекты типа `Currency`.

В классе `Currency` нет никакой связи междy полями `name`, `exRate` и свойствами `Name`, `ExRate`.

```
 public Currency(Currency previous) : this()
 {
   if (previous != null)
   {
     name = previous.name;
     exRate = previous.exRate;
   }
 }
```