# Значение null при записи из datagridview в xml

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, datatable

На форме есть пустая `DataGridView`. Создаю для неё `DataTable`.

```
private void новыйToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Product"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prize"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Count"));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Ввожу в строку `DataGridView` данные и пытаюсь сохранить их в XML.

```
private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);
    DataSet dS = new DataSet();
    dS.Tables.Add(dT);
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
    if (save.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            dS.WriteXml(save.FileName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Метод GetDataTableFromDGV

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Visible)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }
    object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

При попытке открыть сохраненный XML

```
private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (open.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = open.FileName;
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(path);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Всегда получается, что нет последней Column. В методе `GetDataTableFromDGV()` указывает на ошибку `NullReferenceException` в строке:

```
cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
```

Прочитал, что надо изначально задавать `column` в `DataTable` чтобы её избежать, но они уже заданы при создании.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Уважаемый, серьезно, сидел и "гуглил", что же такое "dgv". Сразу расшифровано написать нельзя?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Исправлено. Все, чтобы вы улыбались)

Comment: Ваша ошибка в... `object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];` . Чему будет равен `cellValues[0]`? Я отвечу - NULL, ибо вы просто задали пустой массив объектов. А инициализировать? Ну а вообще, я бы закрыл как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/Что-такое-nullreferenceexception-и-как-мне-исправить-код).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Задал массив, далее прошелся в цикле и записал значения. 
С чего бы ему быть null?
Проблема в том что последний row.Cell[i].value возвращает null хотя в начале у него было задано конкретное value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкиньте полностью метод `GetDataTableFromDGV`.

У вас привязан `DataTable` к `DataGridView`, вот его и берите:

```
var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

Ещё лучше - сделайте его полем класса (формы).

`DataSet` тоже можно полностью выкинуть. Я понимаю, почему вы его используете: не получалось читать данные иначе.

Исходя из вопроса и комментариев, я могу предположить, что в файл не записываются те колонки, в которых нет данных. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно записывать схему вместе с данными. Одновременно решится проблема чтения без датасета.

Запись:

```
dt.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Чтение:

```
dt.ReadXml(path);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Обратите внимание: создавать локальные `DataTable` не нужно! Мы его сделали полем.

Напомню, что `DataSet` тоже не нужен.

Осталось исправить ещё одну строку кода, чтобы всё заработало - дать имя дататейблу при его создании:

```
dt = new DataTable("Products");
```

Это необходимо в отсутствие датасета.