# Проверка на наличие в DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Требуется пройти по DataGridView и найти там определенные данные, введенные с textbox. Как это реализовать?

Пробовал так, получилось но вылетает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.", ругаясь на строку в if.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text.ToString() &&
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == textBox2.Text.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Здарова");
            }
        }
```

Comment: исправил вопрос. получилась проверка, но выдает ошибку

Comment: По этой ошибке есть [канонiчный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Если коротко, то она означает, что какой-то из используемых объектов null. Проверьте какой именно. Предполагаю, что это один из `Value` (напишите если я прав или не прав).

Comment: Для того чтобы разобраться какой именно из объектов принимает значение null делите каждое выражение на части и проверяйте их по одному в режиме отладки. Или посмотрите пример «Цепочка» в [ответе на канонiчный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Comment: @defaultlocale действительно DGV имел пустые ячейки, но в данный момент я их убрал, а ошибка осталась.

Comment: Ну зачем строить гипотезы если можно просто при возникновении ошибки в режиме отладки посмотреть что именно возвращает `null`. Там и будет видно какая это ячейка и что с ней не так.

Comment: @defaultlocale пустых ячеек нет. Но указывает он на ячейку, содержащую числовые данные.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79479/discussion-between-default-locale-and-paul-greengod).