# c# - ошибка Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Мой код (я использую Anglecharp для парсинга значения из html)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда не находит ник то пишет вот такую ошибку - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в полученном html нет элемента, который вы ищете. Проверяйте условия. Приведите образец html содержащий искомый кусок.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (result == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.TextContent))
```

Comment: Или `string.IsNullOrEmpty(result?.TextContent))`  (если версия C# позволит)

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало. А в чём проблемма и как вы решили её ? Я в 1c# новичёк

Comment: @Psazy у Вас нет результата. Объект отсутствует. А Вы пытаетесь прочитать его свойство. Проводя аналогию - Вы хотите узнать цвет двери. А двери нет. Вот и возникает ошибка. Посмотрете здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4?noredirect=1&lq=1