# Выдает ошибку NullReferenceException в месте, где вообще такой ошибки возникнуть не должно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот скрипт :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

bool[] isFull;
public GameObject[] slots;

void Start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
    {
        slots[i] = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InventoryCanvas").transform.Find("Slots").GetChild(i).gameObject;
        isFull[i] = false;

    }
}
```

}

Ошибку выдает на строчке isFull[i] = false;
Без этой строчки всё работает.

Comment: `bool[] isFull` а где выделение памяти?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Ребят, вы серьезно?! Лайкаете, отвечаете на явный дубликат, да еще и где у автора как минимум 3 таких вопроса было, с той же самой ошибкой, закрытые дубликатом. Если он не хочет хотя бы прочитать то, что дают, то лайки то тут к чему? Не понять мне это...

Comment: Пусть везде все и сравнивается к неинициализированой переменной, везде это сводится по-разному. Я читал некоторые тему, но конкретно у себя я не мог понять ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Start() {
  isFull = new bool[slots.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Странно что вчера и без этой штуки все работало... Хотя я не знаю как оно работало, в ошибке разобрался. isFull не был инициализирован.