# Ошибка при работе с программой: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При работе с той частью программы, за которую отвечает этот код, выскакивает исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
C# учу недавно, с такой ошибкой столкнулся впервые. Ниже часть кода с выделенной строкой с ошибкой:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string subj;
         !! subj = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ВидЗанятий"].Value.ToString().Trim();

            if ((subj == "Пр") || (subj == "Лек") || (subj == "Лаб"))
            {
                textBox1.Text += "Известный тип" + "\r" + "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text += "Неизвестный тип занятий" + "\r" + "\n";
            }                
        }
```

Comment: можно к вопросу добавить StackTrace? так как не понятно из вопроса где конкретно он не находит! (То ли записи, то ли столбца)...

Comment: У вас ячейка отсутствует,поэтому и ругается.

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавить столбец. Либо поставить ловушку `try{}catch{}`

Comment: вам нужно проверять `if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ВидЗанятий"].Value !=null)`  итолько потом проверять какое значение, если нужно выводить как ненужное/неустановленое значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что, значение в ячейке не установлено, вам необходимо сделать следующее:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var cell =dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ВидЗанятий"].Value;
    if(cell!=null)
    {
         subj =cell.ToString().Trim();
         if ((subj == "Пр") || (subj == "Лек") || (subj == "Лаб"))
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Известный тип" + "\r" + "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Неизвестный тип занятий" + "\r" + "\n";
        }                                       
    }
    else
     {
         textBox1.Text += "Пустое значение" + "\r" + "\n";
     }

}
```

В результате ваша проблема должна исчезнуть.

Comment: @ViktorBezrukov надеюсь вам понравится мое решение.