# Newtonsoft JSON ошибка при Split'e Array

Tags: c#, json, парсер

```
    foreach (Entitlement entitlement in game.entitlements)
    {
         string[] array = entitlement.offerPath.Split(new char[] { '/' })[2].Split(new char[] { '-' });
         text = text + string.Join(" ", array) + "\r\n";
    }
```

Добрый день! Парсю json ответ сайта, и пытаюсь убрать ненужные символы с помощью Split, однако именно на сплите получаю ошибку: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Как я заметил, ошибку получаю если среди данных есть пустые строки, потому что эта ошибка возникает далеко не при всех данных. Буду благодарен за Ваше решение моей проблемы!

Comment: На приведённых данных не падает.

Comment: Не понял Вас. Я привел весь код, который использую. Что не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @S3RL Ваш код падает на каких-то данных, но не на этих. Приведите код, на которых падает. Желательно обрезать код, чтобы вопрос не был простыней текста. См. [как создать хороший mvce](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). У вас нет проблем с json.net у вас проблемы со стрингой (offerPath) которую вы режете сплитом при этом рассчитывая, что всегда будет [2] И кстати зачем убирать ненужные символы через `string.Split()`, когда можно воспользоваться `.Replace()`?

Comment: @AK Даже если просто Split('/') сделать, без [2] - результат тот же. Если сделать .Replace() - результат тот же. Подредактировал вопрос, добавив в него данные, которые находятся в offerPath!

Comment: @S3RL и вас никак пустое место не смущает? `Как я заметил, ошибку получаю если среди данных есть пустые строки` - я дал вам ссылку на дубликат, ознакомьтесь

Comment: @tym32167 Ознакомился, но в силу своей неопытности ничего не понял. Зачем мне выбрасывать exception или заменять на стандартное значение пропуски? Мне от пустых строк как-то нужно избавиться, а потом работать с остальными данными, чтобы при удалении ненужных мне символов не выбивало Exception.

Comment: проблема в том, что после парсинга у вас поле `offerPath` в некоторых случаях равняется `null`, потому, когда вы вызываете какие то методы на такой строке, вот тут например, `entitlement.offerPath.Split(...)`, вы получаете ошибку.

Comment: @tym32167 Это я понял, я не понял как это исправить. Исходя из приведенного Вами примера, можно обрабатывать с помощью exception, только что мне это даст?

Comment: ну а какой результат вы хотите получить в том случае, когда у вас нет данных в поле `entitlement.offerPath` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Я хочу пропустить эти пустые данные, и работать с другими.

Comment: Тогда вам надо `foreach (Entitlement entitlement in game.entitlements.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.offerPath))) {....}`

Comment: @tym32167 Именно это мне и нужно было. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю за помощь @tym32167 !
Для решения моей проблемы, нужно убрать пустые строки с данными (null), и работать с остальными. В таком случае, программа не будет выдавать исключение при обработке пустых данных.
Убираем пустые данные из string[] array с помощью `x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.offerPath)`

Получится: `foreach (Entitlement entitlement in game.entitlements.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.offerPath))) {....}`