# Ошибка NullReferenceException: Не выбираются специалисты

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Прошу помочь с данной ошибкой: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

HistoriesController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{

    var mymodel = new ViewModel();
    mymodel.Histories = await _context.Histories.Include(h => h.Doctor).Include(h => h.Patient).ToListAsync();
    mymodel.Specialists = await _context.Specialists.Include(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();
    return View(mymodel);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (Specialist specialist in Model.Specialists)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => specialist.Name)
    </td>
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Specialist> Specialists { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Мгм. Вообще-то обычно Name - это строка, а вы ей делаете `.Include` как будто это класс. Уберите `.Include(s => s.Name)` - ошибка пропала? Кроме того, у вас не заполняется Patients  и Doctors - и если у вас в index или его дочерних представлениях идёт обращение к ним - то на них и грохнется.

Comment: ошибка в строке mymodel.Specialists = await _context.Specialists.Include(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();

Comment: Убрал .Include(s => s.Name) Ошибка пропала.Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите какая штука.

Вот есть у вас допустим сущность специалист:

```
public class Specialists
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

вам нужно запомнить, что .Include не применяется ни к int, ни к string - только к другим композитным объектам (проще - таблицам).

Вот когда у вас есть история болезни (кого лечим, кто лечит):

```
public class History
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public virtual Doctor Who { get; set;}
    public virtual Patient Whom{ get; set;}
}
```

Вот только такие поля могут быть подключены - Doctor, Patient. Т.е. имена классов.

Делая выборку из специалиастов - все простые поля (имеющие типы int, double, string) подтягиваются автоматически. А вот обращения к другим таблицам (sql join) их нужно (если они нужны в выборке) объявлять явно.