# Unity - OnClick событие не вешается через скрипт

Tags: unity3d

```
UITextButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(this.AcceptMe);

public void AcceptMe() {
    print(this.transform.parent.name);
}
```

При запуске игры показывается ошибка: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, указывает на первую строчку. Почему так может быть?

Comment: либо UITextButton у вас null, либо на объекте нет компонента Button

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `NullReferenceException` происходит тогда, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться через точку (например: `myClass.GetAnything()`) к `null`, то есть к пустоте (подробнее см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

Применительно к вашему случаю, ошибка вылетает из-за того что:

А) `UITextButton` ссылается на `null`, то есть она пустая.

Б) на объекте, что хранится в `UITextButton` не висит компонент `Button`.

Мой совет: разбейте код на несколько частей, чтобы понять, что именно вызывает ошибку. Сделать это можно так:

```
if (UITextButton != null)
{
    var button = UITextButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.onClick.AddListener(this.AcceptMe);
    }
    else Debug.Log("На объекте нет компонента Button!");
}
else Debug.Log("Объект UITextButton == null!");
```