# XML файл при чтении выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, xml

Пытаюсь прочитать XML файл.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(filePath);
XmlNodeList cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//Row/Cell");

foreach (XmlNode node in cellList);
            {
                string iNumber = cellList[0].Attributes[0].Value;
                string iAccountNumber = cellList[1].Attributes[0].Value;
                string name = cellList[2].Attributes[0].Value;
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." указывая на строку:

```
string iNumber = cellList[0].Attributes[0].Value;
```

Что делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот фрагмент из xml файла. Перед этим фрагментом много информации с совершенно разными тегами, которые не нужно читать.

```
<Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">340054288</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">ИВАНОВ  К. С.</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">НОВОСТРОЙКА  28 ГА</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">271</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">108.8200</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">2015-061195</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">DDS 232</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2017-09-05T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Элементов с тегом Row много в файле, именно их нужно читать.

Comment: Какое-то из свойств/переменных в этой строке равно null. Вам нужно определить какое и построить вопрос в форме: «почему `xxx` принимает значение null». Также приложите пример XML на котором воспроизводится ошибка. Вообще, по этому типу ошибки есть вопрос с набором рецептов для анализа проблемы: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/).

Comment: А почему вы в ``foreach`` цикле не используете переменную ``node``? Вот [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.2.php) очень хорошее описание работы с xml структурами.

Comment: либо `filePath` либо `cellList` у вас пустой, ставте точку останова, и смотриче в чем проблема...скорее всего у вас в `XmlNodeList cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//Row/Cell");` неверный путь (но это не 100%)

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример Вашего XML.

Comment: @XelaNimed  добавил пример.

Comment: @XelaNimed в текст вопроса, посмотрите, обновите страничку

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Проверил. filePath и cellList не равны null, а вот cellList[0] = null, как это может быть?

Comment: сделайте тогда проверку `if (node != null) {ваш код}`. И у вас нет чего-то на подобии `XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно сказать почему происходит ошибка я не могу, но хочу отметить несколько моментов:

### Точка с запятой

У Вас точка с запятой после `foreach`, уберите ее:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in cellList); --вот
```

Из-за нее цикл работает в пустую, а все, что идет после цикла, считается отдельным блоком и к циклу не относится. Соответственно, даже если не будет найдено ни одной ячейки код будет обращаться к `cellList[0]`.

Обычно среда разработки подчеркивает или как-то выделяет лишние символы в таких случаях, обращайте внимание на такие подсказки.

### cellList[0] вернет null для пустого списка

Для пустого списка `cellList[0]` как это ни странно не выкинет исключение, а вернет null, о чем написано в [документации XmlNodeList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist.itemof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNodeList_ItemOf_System_Int32_):

> The XmlNode with the specified index in the collection. **If index is greater than or equal to the number of nodes in the list, this returns null.**

### Не находятся ячейки

Из вышесказанного следует, что по каким-то причинам `SelectNodes` возвращает пустой результат. Чтобы мы могли точно определить почему Вам нужно создать воспроизводимый пример, а именно выложить XML-файл на котором ошибка воспроизводится.

> Вот фрагмент из xml файла. Перед этим фрагментом много информации с совершенно разными тегами, которые не нужно читать.

В этом случае лучше будет сделать так: удалить из XML файла «много информации» как перед так и после этого фрагмента, оставить только корневой элемент и проверить воспроизводится ли ошибка на таком файле. Если не воспроизводится, то значит дело как раз в удаленной части и нужно разбираться с ней. Если воспроизводится, то у Вас получится минимальный, но при этом полноценный, пример, который можно выложить в вопросе. И на нем уже будет видно в чем именно ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу определить почему у Вас не работает, но нижеприведённый код, основанный на Ваших данных, отрабатывает без проблем:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
        xmlString += "<rootNode xmlns:ss=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
        xmlString += "<Row>";
        xmlString += "<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s69\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">1</Data></Cell>";
        xmlString += "<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s69\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">340054288</Data></Cell>";
        xmlString += "<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s69\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">ИВАНОВ К. С.</Data></Cell>";
        xmlString += "<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s69\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">НОВОСТРОЙКА  28 ГА</Data></Cell>";
        xmlString += "</Row>";
        xmlString += "</rootNode>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        using(XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Row/Cell")){
            foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList){
                Console.WriteLine("innerText: " + node.InnerText + 
                ", argument[0]: " + node.Attributes[0].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит

```
innerText: 1, argument[0]: s69
innerText: 340054288, argument[0]: s69
innerText: ИВАНОВ К. С., argument[0]: s69
innerText: НОВОСТРОЙКА  28 ГА, argument[0]: s69
```

Поиграться можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNSb3F).

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [XmlDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [XmlDocument.DocumentElement](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [XmlNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [XmlNode.SelectNodes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: премного благодарен! Скажите, при большом размере файла, так как считывание займёт всю память, требуют использования метода XmlRead. Как использовать XmlRead в моём случае с моим xml?

Comment: @Forward https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441694/3129992

Comment: @Forward - если у вас затруднения с использованием `XmlReader`, то создайте новую тему. Не задавайте такие вопросы в комментариях.