# Ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#

В процессе работы программы формируется ошибка System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." при попытке присвоить значение product.barcodes[0]= "2990000000002";
Не пойму в чем дело. Я так понимаю ошибка связана с тем,  что обращаюсь к элементу списка.

```
public class Product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int departmentId { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public List<string> barcodes { get; set; }
    public string tax { get; set; }
}

Product product = new Product();
product.name = "Проверка";
product.type = "COUNTABLE";
product.departmentId = 114097;
product.quantity = 1000;
product.price = 333;
product.barcodes[0]= "2990000000002"; //ОШИБКА НА ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ

product.tax = "NDS_NO_TAX";
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: "[Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)"

Comment: barcodes.Add("2990000000002")

Comment: @dmtr, это выкинет ту же ошибку)

Comment: Во-первых прочитайте, что такое ссылочные и значимые типы и их значения по умолчанию. Во-вторых, при возникновении ошибок пользуйтесь точками остановки (breakpoint) в IDE, так Вы сможете увидеть значение переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к неинициализированной перемененной barcodes.
Можно инициализировать ее 3-мя способами:
1:

```
public List<string> barcodes { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

2:

```
public Product()
{
    barcodes = new List<string>();
}
```

3:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.barcodes = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Спасибо, всем за ответы
Решил так: List<string> barcodes = new List<string>();