# Почему возникает NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#

Выполняю одно из заданий курса по С#, которое звучит так:

---

> Создать класс, представляющий учебный класс ClassRoom. Создайте класс
>   ученик Pupil. В теле класса создайте методы void Study(), void Read(),
>   void Write(), void Relax(). Создайте 3 производных класса
>   ExcelentPupil, GoodPupil, BadPupil от класса базового класса Pupil и
>   переопределите каждый из методов, в зависимости от успеваемости
>   ученика. Конструктор класса ClassRoom принимает аргументы типа Pupil,
>   класс должен состоять из 4 учеников. Предусмотрите возможность того,
>   что пользователь может передать 2 или 3 аргумента. Выведите информацию
>   о том, как все ученики экземпляра класса ClassRoom умеют учиться,
>   читать, писать, отдыхать.

---

Основные пункты задания, которые определены в условии я, хоть и примитивно, но выполнил и решил добавить ещё метод GetInfo(), который бы выводил информацию о числе отличников, хорошистов и плохих учеников в классе.
Для этого я обьявил массив в классе ClassRoom, который по идее должен принимать различное число элементов(инициализация проходив конструкторе).

В методе GetInfo() происходит перебор элементов массива и вычисление чисел различных видов учеников в классе.

Проблема состоит в том, что во время выполнения программы возникает исключение типа NullReferenceException, на строках инициализации массива. Выглядит так, будто поля pupil_1 - pupil_4  не определены, хотя выше в теле конструктора они определяются ссылками на обьекты.

Кроме того, возникает предупреждение "*Field 'ClassRoom.pupils' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null*", чего тоже вроде как не должно быть, судя по тому, что я как раз таки и пытаюсь определить массив.

Делал различные проверки и  никак не могу понять, в чём же проблема.

Буду очень рад и признателен любой подсказке.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExcelentPupil a = new ExcelentPupil();
        GoodPupil b = new GoodPupil();
        BadPupil c = new BadPupil();

        ClassRoom class1 = new ClassRoom(a, b, c, c);
        ClassRoom class2 = new ClassRoom(a, b);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

abstract class Pupil
{
    public abstract string Study();
    public abstract string Read();
    public abstract string Write();
    public abstract string Relax();
}

class ExcelentPupil : Pupil
{
    public override string Read()
    {
        return "читает отлично";
    }
    public override string Study()
    {
        return "учится отлично";
    }
    public override string Write()
    {
        return "пишет отлично";
    }
    public override string Relax()
    {
        return "отдыхает отлично";
    }
}
class GoodPupil : Pupil
{
    public override string Read()
    {
        return "читает хорошо";
    }
    public override string Study()
    {
        return "учится хорошо";
    }
    public override string Write()
    {
        return "пишет хорошо";
    }
    public override string Relax()
    {
        return "отдыхает хорошо";
    }
}
class BadPupil : Pupil
{
    public override string Read()
    {
        return "читает плохо";
    }
    public override string Study()
    {
        return "учится плохо";
    }
    public override string Write()
    {
        return "пишет плохо";
    }
    public override string Relax()
    {
        return "отдыхает плохо";
    }
}

class ClassRoom
{
    Pupil pupil_1;
    Pupil pupil_2;
    Pupil pupil_3;
    Pupil pupil_4;
    Pupil[] pupils;

    public ClassRoom(Pupil pupil_1, Pupil pupil_2, Pupil pupil_3, Pupil pupil_4)
    {
        this.pupil_1 = pupil_1;
        this.pupil_2 = pupil_2;
        this.pupil_3 = pupil_3;
        this.pupil_4 = pupil_4;


        Console.WriteLine($"1 ученик {pupil_1.Read()}, {pupil_1.Study()}, {pupil_1.Write()}, {pupil_1.Relax()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"2 ученик {pupil_2.Read()}, {pupil_2.Study()}, {pupil_2.Write()}, {pupil_2.Relax()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"3 ученик {pupil_3.Read()}, {pupil_3.Study()}, {pupil_3.Write()}, {pupil_3.Relax()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"4 ученик {pupil_4.Read()}, {pupil_4.Study()}, {pupil_4.Write()}, {pupil_4.Relax()}");

        pupils[0] = this.pupil_1;
        pupils[1] = this.pupil_2;
        pupils[2] = this.pupil_3;
        pupils[3] = this.pupil_4;

        GetInfo();

    }
    public ClassRoom(Pupil pupil_1, Pupil pupil_2)
    {
        this.pupil_1 = pupil_1;
        this.pupil_2 = pupil_2;

        Console.WriteLine($"1 ученик {pupil_1.Read()}, {pupil_1.Study()}, {pupil_1.Write()}, {pupil_1.Relax()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"2 ученик {pupil_2.Read()}, {pupil_2.Study()}, {pupil_2.Write()}, {pupil_2.Relax()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Про 3 и 4 учеников ничего не известно");

        pupils[0] = pupil_1;
        pupils[1] = pupil_2;

        GetInfo();

    }
    public void GetInfo()
    {
        byte numOfExlecent = 0, numOfGood = 0, numOfBad = 0;

        foreach (Pupil i in pupils)
        {
            if (i is ExcelentPupil) numOfExlecent++;
            else if (i is GoodPupil) numOfGood++;
            else if (i is BadPupil) numOfBad++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"В классе {numOfExlecent} отличных, {numOfGood} хороших и {numOfBad} плохих учеников");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)?
2. Причина в том, что массив `pupils` не инициализирован.

---

```
class ClassRoom
{
    Pupil pupil_1;
    Pupil pupil_2;
    Pupil pupil_3;
    Pupil pupil_4;
    Pupil[] pupils = new Pupil[4];

...
```

Comment: Быстрая инициализация работает в абстрактном классе. По ссылке вы найдете детальное объяснение вашего случая :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)