# Ошибка "GetMeAsync().Result"

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Скорее всего, проблема банальна, но я решение в интернете так и не нашёл.[image: Скриншот ошибки]
Прошу объяснить, в чём проблема, заранее спасибо.
(токен рабочий)

```
using MihaZupan;
using System;
using Telegram.Bot;

    namespace ConsoleApp2
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static ITelegramBotClient botClient;

            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                    var proxy = new HttpToSocks5Proxy("216.144.230.233", 15993);
                    var Bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient("1048644182:AAFgwYVFE3WM_PmtUngWmlNF_bHfq_dcVnQ", proxy);
                    var me = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(me.Id + "<- ID");
                    Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Код и ошибку лучше прилагать текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: да, но на скриншоте видна ошибка так, как она есть.

Comment: botClient не создан... среда его даже зелененьким подсветила для вас

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в `var Bot = ...` кладете экземпляр бота, значит и методы вызывать нужно из него.

```
var me = Bot.GetMeAsync().Result;
```

Comment: изменил строчку,но всё равно не отвечает,прокси проверил. "private static ITelegramBotClient botClient;" нужно убрать?

Comment: @Игорь Отвечает - не отвечает, это уже другая проблема и другой вопрос, смотрите проблему в прокси. Если ошибка NPE ушла, значит уже гуд, да уберите.