# Сортировка DataGridView с помощью ComboBox c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

После выбора в combobox какой-нибудь строки выходит ошибка

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[comboBox1.Text], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
[image: Вот такая ошибка выходит]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете вкратце показать пример на моем коде

Comment: Пример чего? Вы получаете NULL, смотрите что у вас NULL и исправляйте. Наверно у вас `comboBox1.Text` имеет не то значение изначально, `dataGridView1.Columns[comboBox1.Text]` выдает вам NULL. Выносите тогда это в отдельную переменную и проверяйте на NULL, если не NULL - выполняйте `dataGridView1.Sort(..)`.