# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, model, vr

Пытаюсь сделать основу vr игры по туториалу, но тут всплыла проблема
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HandPresence.Update () (at Assets/HandPresence.cs:56)
и из-за этой проблемы у меня на контроллерах отображается и контроллеры и "руки". Пытался убирать некоторые части кода и после того как убрать код в update ничего не меняется.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот сам код (пометил 56 строку) и вот ссылка на видео человека с таймкодом https://youtu.be/VdT0zMcggTQ?t=912

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class HandPresence : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool showController = false;
    public InputDeviceCharacteristics controllerCharacteristics;
    public List<GameObject> controllerPrefabs;
    public GameObject handModelPrefab;

    private InputDevice targetDevice;
    private GameObject spawnedController;
    private GameObject spawnedHandModel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        List<InputDevice> devices = new List<InputDevice>();
        // InputDeviceCharacteristics rightControllerCharacteristics = InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
        InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(controllerCharacteristics, devices);

        foreach (var item in devices)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.name + item.characteristics);
        }
        if (devices.Count > 0) 
        {
            targetDevice = devices[0];
            GameObject prefab = controllerPrefabs.Find(controller => controller.name == targetDevice.name);
            if (prefab)
            {
                Instantiate(prefab, transform);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Did not find corresponding controller model");
                spawnedController = Instantiate(controllerPrefabs[0], transform);
            }

            spawnedHandModel = Instantiate(handModelPrefab, transform);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(showController)
        {
            spawnedHandModel.SetActive(false);
            spawnedController.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            spawnedController.SetActive(false); // 56 строка
            spawnedHandModel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, что надо так:

```
    if (prefab)
    {
        spawnedController = Instantiate(prefab, transform); # исправил эту строку
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Did not find corresponding controller model");
        spawnedController = Instantiate(controllerPrefabs[0], transform);
    }
```

Иначе при выполнении условия `if (prefab)` у вас `spawnedController` остаётся не инициализированным и потом вылазит ошибка как-раз про это.
Я так то Unity 3D уже не помню, хотя и изучал, но по логике выходит как-то так.

Comment: О боже спасибо. Всем дискордом пытались найти ошибку и не получалось. А вы так быстро посмотрели и исправили. Благодарю всем сердцем.

Comment: Без вас бы голову ломал неделю так точно