# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ObjectsInformation.Start ()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класc ObjectsInformation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ObjectsInformation : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Build Name")]
public string BuildName;
[Header("Build Information")]
public int BlockCount;
public Difficult difficult;
[Header("Updates")]
public List<Updates> levelsUpdate = new List<Updates>();
[Header("NowLevel")]
public int Level;

public enum Difficult
{
    Easy, 
    Normal,
    Hard,
    Very_Hard
};

private void Start()
{
    GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = BuildName;
    if (Level == 0) transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Построить";
     else transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Улучшить";
}
```

}

класс Update из которых состоит лист в ObjectsInformation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class Updates
{
public int level;
public Image Image;
public GameObject Object;
}
```

Выдает NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ObjectsInformation.Start () в

```
if (Level == 0) transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Построить";
     else transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Улучшить";
```

Объясните в чем проблема пожалуйста...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 2):

NullReferenceException: то к чему вы обращаетесь не существует.

Компонент `Text` в вашем случае.

```
if (transform.childCount >= 2) {
    Text BtnText = transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>();
    if (BtnText != null)
        BtnText.text = Level == 0 ? "Построить" : "Улучшить";
}
```

`ObjectsInformation` нету нужды быть `MonoBehaviour`. Лучше [ScriptableObject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY).

То что у вас происходит в `Start` вообще не имеет дело к `ObjectsInformation`, это должен быть отдельный `MonoBehaviour` с полями ссылок на объекты `Text`, без всяких `GetChild`;

Answer (score 0):

У объекта к которому вы обращаетесь (`transform.GetChild(2)`) не существует компонента типа `<Text>`.

Убедитесь, что вы обращаетесь именно к тому объекту, выведя в консоль его имя:

```
Debug.Log(transform.GetChild(2).ToString());
```

Убедитесь, что у этого объекта есть компонент `Text`.

PS: возможно, стоит обратить внимание на поиск объекта по тегу. Это будет более надежно, и не сильно повлияет на производительность, если произвести такую операцию в методе `Start` и потом обращаться к нему через сохраненную ссылку.