# Ошибка при выводе зубчатого массива в C#

Tags: c#

Есть код который делает зубчатый массив, затем присваевает ему рандомные значения и выводит сам массив(ну по крайне мере оно так должно работать по моему мнению).Но он выводит ошибку (см. прикрепленый скрин) и говорит что ошибка на 19 строчке кода хотя я там не нашёл ни одной ошибке да и сама visual studio говориит что код чист.Можете подсказать почему так происходить и как это пофиксить.Заранее спасибо

```
using System;

namespace ProgramForPorzhat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] nums = new int[3][];

            nums[0] = new int[2];
            nums[0] = new int[4];
            nums[0] = new int[6];

            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    nums[i][j] = random.Next(100);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(nums[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Вот он скрин]

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом, а не ссылками. Ссылки устареют и потом поди разбери, что вы тут спрашивали. В самом коде вы 3 раза устанавливаете `nums[0]`, а как насчет `nums[1]` и `nums[2]`?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо прост там показывали на 19 строчку кода и  проверял циклы а там оказывается проблема в создание массива.Спасибо возьму на заметку что код надо кидать текстом

Comment: У вас в тексте ошибки написано, что осутсвует объект или ссылка на объект. Это, по сути, сразу указывает куда копать. Больше информации [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/179763)

Comment: `nums[0] = new int[2]; nums[1] = new int[4]; nums[2] = new int[6];`