# Не перебирается коллекция элементов в GroupBox C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Не могу понять, как перебрать все радиобаттоны в `GroupBox`. Попробовал сделать в C#-стайл:

```
for each (Control c in Age_GBox.Controls)
{
    MessageBox::Show(c.ToString());
}
```

Ругается на то, что `.Controls` возвращает `System::Object^`.
Ок, поменял тип. Сделал так:

```
for each (System::Object ^ c in Age_GBox.Controls)
{
    MessageBox::Show(c.ToString());
}
```

Заработало, тип элементов выводит. Попытался на радостях получить доступ к свойству `Checked` да и вообще любому другом свойству. Не выходит, этот объект вообще не имеет никаких свойств, кроме стандартных вроде `Clear`, `Add`, `ToString` и пр. Что не так?

Comment: В `for each` укажите `Control^` - знак `^` обязателен в данном контексте.

Comment: Вы сперва поставили метку C++. (_Устало, в сотый раз_) C++ и C++/CLI - это **разные** языки! То, что у них совпадают первые символы, значит не больше, чем совпадающие первые символы в языках Java и JavaScript, или python и pascal. Если вы учите именно C++, то не трогайте C++/CLI. И, соответственно, забудьте про WinForms, потому что этот GUI-фреймворк под платформу .NET.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием забыл про C++/CLI, но (Устало, в сотый раз), наши устаревшие университеты, которые все еще даже используют C++98 стандарт требуют от меня лабораторные по C++/CLI и WinForms. Я бы с удовольствием перешел в C# для этих целей, но отчисляться из-за невыполнения лабораторных мне не хочется.

Comment: Visual Studio - хорошая IDE. Но я всегда говорил и буду говорить, что для изучения C++ лучше взять другую IDE. Потому что VS позволяет писать на многих языках, в том числе C++/CLI. Вот начинающие и путаются. После знакомства с консольными программками, хочется попробовать ГУЙ, вот и натыкаются рано или поздно на WinForms, а это совсем другая платформа! В итоге учат то, что никогда не пригодится.

Comment: Тогда не ставьте метку C++! Даже не упоминайте этот язык в контексте WinForms!

Comment: Увы, но я еще с первого курса понял, что тут меня ничему не научат. Но, чтобы не вылететь из университета или со стипендии, приходится как раз таки учить эти ненужные знания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что если при итерации используется объект базового класса `System::Object`, то и методы у него будут доступны только этого класса. Если нужно вызвать метод какого-то производного класса, то сначала нужно убедиться, что объект реально соответствует этому классу, и уже после вызвать нужный метод. Делается это путём приведения типов. См.  [`operator dynamic_cast`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dynamic-cast-operator?view=msvc-160):

```
RadioButton^ rb = dynamic_cast<RadioButton^>(c);
if (rb != nullptr) { 
   bool checked = rb->Checked(); 
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, но не выходит. Компилятор ругается на то, что нельзя использовать указатели на элементы C++/cli. Или я неправильно его использую?

RadioButton* c = dynamic_cast <RadioButton*> (c);

Comment: @CSharpLooser указатели управляемые должны быть (с шапочкой `^`). По ссылке есть пример: `dynamic_cast<String^>(o)`. Добавил в ответ пример кода.

Comment: Увы, но ваш пример не работает. Выдает исключение: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." Вот такой код: RadioButton^ rb = dynamic_cast<RadioButton^>(c);
   bool checked = rb->Checked;
   MessageBox::Show(checked.ToString()); Ругается на строку, где мы вызываем свойство Checked

Comment: @CSharpLooser так надо проверку `rb` на `nullptr` добавить после каста. Ведь на форме могут и другие контролы быть помимо радиокнопки. По `NullReferenceException` читайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/176217).

Comment: Для теста я специально оставил только Радиобаттоны. Если проверять на nullptr, то ни разу не вызывается все, что под условием. То есть rb Всегда nullptr

Comment: @CSharpLooser если `dynamic_cast` вернул null, значит тип не тот. Надо проверить что там вообще за типы перебираются, например, через какой-нибудь `с->GetType()->ToString()` или нечто подобное.