# Ошибка при удалении не существующей строки из DataGridView

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                //Удаление данных в  dataGridView и в базе данной
                // int a = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                // dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[a]);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM school_graduate WHERE id=@id", con);
                if (dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                int id = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                con.Open(); //Открываем подключение
               
                try
                {
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Запись удалена");
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Удалить не удалось!");
                }
                Bind();
               
                con.Close();
            }
```

Записи удаляются если они существуют в  dataGridView1 , если записей уже нет и нажать на кнопку удалить то выходит ошибка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите что я делаю не так.

Comment: Значит нужно проверять наличие записей в DGV прежде чем приступать к удалению.

Comment: К примеру у вас есть переменная `row`, она имеет значение `null`, и если вы обратитесь к полям или свойствам этой переменной `row.Index` или `row.Value`, вы получите `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: `if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null) return;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ . Я сделал так   ``` if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("В базе данных не существует записей");
                    return;
                } ```