# Ошибка какая то

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Что это за ошибка: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ScoreMeneger.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Scores/ScoreMeneger.cs:20)?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreMeneger : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int score;
  [SerializeField] Text ScoreMN;

  public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
      score++;
    }
  }
  void Update()
  {
    ScoreMN.text = score.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Ошибка какая-то` - это **самый топовый заголовок**, который я вообще *когда-либо* видел. Требую, легализовать также: `Чета глючит`, `Не фурычит`, `ХЭЭЭЛП!`

Answer (score 1):

[NullReferenceException](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html) обозначает, что вы пытаетесь <strike>достучаться</strike> работать с переменной, значение которой равно null. Это тема обсуждалась и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), на StackOverflow.

Конкретно по вашему коду, у вас есть переменная ScoreMN, которая, очевидно, должна быть присвоена в инспекторе. Вы ее, похоже, не присвоили. Она равна `null`, а вы путаетесь получить у нее свойство `text`. Получается, ваша 20-я строка выглядит так: `null.text`, что разумеется не работает. Вам следует перетянуть объект с компонентом [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) в инспекторе к этой переменной.

> Между прочим, в инструкции о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) прописано, что вам следует сначала поискать ответы на свой вопрос в Интернете, а уже потом, если не нашли, задавать вопрос. Сейчас его вполне можно закрыть как дубликат по вышеуказанной мною ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

В переменную `ScoreMN` ничего не присвоено. Наверное в инспекторе в это поле забыли закинуть нужный объект где есть компонент `Text`