# NullReferenceException при запуске корутины

Tags: c#, unity3d, coroutine

MonoBehaviour - базовый класс в Unity, в котором реализованы все основные функции, методы и обработчики...
Сделаю условный пример:

Есть 2 класса:

```
// 1 - ый класс:
public class HttpRequest : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public delegate void DelegateAnswer(string j);
    //public event DelegateAnswer Emit_answer;

    private string url = "http://localhost";
    private string port = ":5555";


    public void POST(string dataForSending) {
        StartCoroutine(PostRequest(dataForSending)); // !!! ОШИБКА В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ ВОЗНИКАЕТ !!!
    }

    public IEnumerator PostRequest(string json) {
        UnityWebRequest req = new UnityWebRequest(url + port, "POST");
        byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
        req.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonToSend);
        req.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        req.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return req.SendWebRequest();

        if (!req.isNetworkError) {
            json = req.downloadHandler.text;
            //Emit_answer(json);
        }
    }
}
```

ОШИБКА: `NullReferenceException`

```
// 2-ой класс:
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HttpRequest httpRequest;
    private string statusOfWaiting = "";

void Start()
    {
        httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.Emit_answer += Checking;

        httpRequest.POST("CkeckOnUniqNickname|" + chInfo.Nickname);
        statusOfWaiting = "CkeckOnUniqNickname";
    }
}
```

Подскажите, может кто знает, что не так сделано?

Возможно стоило вызывать только метод возвращающий Ienumerator для запуска корутины в классе, в котором располагается сам объект. Но Мне бы хотелось бы построить такой вот класс HttpRequest, который бы все делал бы внутри себя и возвращал бы ответ при помощи сигнала и слота.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Вопросы разные так или иначе, так как явно здесь нет null. Объект класса  унаследованого от MonoBiheviour который имеет все нужные для работы метода создается. Поэтому и непонятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать конструктор у класса HttpReqest, который наследует `MonoBehaviour`. При разработке на юнити, следует отказаться от использования конструкторов для `MonoBehaviour` классов. Заместо конструктора юнити предлагает методы `Awake()` и `Start()`. Все дело в том, что между обычным и `MonoBehaviour` классом есть большая разница. `MonoBehaviour`  класс подразумевает собой объект (gameobject) на сцене в юнити, что по факту является ресурсом и требует времени на создание\загрузку. Юнити использует конструкторы `MonoBehaviour` классов для своих нужд и в свое время за кулисами вашего кода. На эту тему, вы можете прочитать множество [вопросов](https://answers.unity.com/questions/862032/c-constructor-in-monobehaviour.html) и статей в интернете.

Думаю в вашем коде проблема может быть связана с тем, что вы создаете `HttpRequest` с помощью конструктора и сразу заставляете его исполнить какие-то действия (в корутине). Но на момент вызова этого кода у вас нет никакой гарантии, что стоящий за этим классом gameObject уже был создан и проинициализирован (а как все знают у любого gameObject есть компоненты типа `Transform`\ `RectTransform`, которые тоже наверняка требуют времени на инициализацию). Таким образом вы пытаетесь стартовать корутину на объекте, которого может еще не быть.

На вашем месте, я бы не стал наследовать `HttpRequest` от `MonoBehaviour`, как минимум потому, что ему не нужен никакой функционал. А gameobject для запуска корутины внутри этого класса можно передать и как параметр в методе.

Либо можете попробовать поправить код минимальной кровью - заменить вызов конструктора на вызов метода [AddComponent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html), оставив при этом `HttpRequest` наследником `MonoBehaviour` - тогда и HttpeRequest и Menu будут висеть на одном и том же gameObject и все должно быть в порядке.

Comment: Я думаю, это самый ахренительный ответ в моей жизни =)) Я не пробовал еще, так как был занят. Но уверен, что вы правы. Думаю так и есть. Я как то об этом не подумал. Сразу видно профи гейм дева !