# Проблема с экспортом из DataGrid в Excel WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid, export

введите сюда описание изображенияРебят, выручайте. Я раньше работал с WindowsForm и недавно перешел на WindowsPresentationForms. Проблема заключается в экспорте из таблицы в excel. Все что отображается в таблице (находится в зоне видимости), он экспортирует, а все что не отображено (скрыто), он выдает ошибку Null, якобы там пусто. Собственно говоря ошибка в этом месте.

```
TextBlock b = WPFDataGrid_result.Columns[i].GetCellContent(WPFDataGrid_result.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
```

Сама ошибка

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
b было null.
```

Ссылка на скриншот как выглядит добавление [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Скриншот самого результата[image: 2] Скрин самой ошибки[image: 3]

Вот код, который записан у меня на xaml для datagdrid

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="WPFDataGrid_result" Height="200" Width="auto" FontSize="18" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,30,15,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наименование метрики" Width="500" Binding="{Binding CollectionRowsResult_Name_metrika}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="№ образца" Width="150" Binding="{Binding CollectionRowsResult_Nomer_obr}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Результат" Width="150" Binding="{Binding CollectionRowsResult_Result}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFB4B4B4"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                    <Setter Property="FixedPage.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

А вот так выглядит код заполнение таблицы на C#

```
  public class CollectionRows
    {
        public float CollectionRows_Obr { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_Vn_Vid { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_Vkyc { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_Color { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_Zapax { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_CBPBBB { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_CFCU { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_PCU { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_RM { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_RCM { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_CP { get; set; }
        public float CollectionRows_OO { get; set; }
    }

  private void добавление_в_таблицу()
        {
            massive[k, 0] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Obr.Text);
            massive[k, 1] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Vn_vid.Text);
            massive[k, 2] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Vkyc.Text);
            massive[k, 3] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Color.Text);
            massive[k, 4] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_zapax.Text);
            massive[k, 5] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CBPBBB.Text);
            massive[k, 6] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CFCU.Text);
            massive[k, 7] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_PCU.Text);
            massive[k, 8] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_RM.Text);
            massive[k, 9] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_RCM.Text);
            massive[k, 10] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CP.Text);
            massive[k, 11] = Convert.ToSingle(TB_OO.Text);
            CollectionRows information = new CollectionRows();
            information.CollectionRows_Obr = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Obr.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_Vn_Vid = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Vn_vid.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_Vkyc = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Vkyc.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_Color = Convert.ToSingle(TB_Color.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_Zapax = Convert.ToSingle(TB_zapax.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_CBPBBB = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CBPBBB.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_CFCU = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CFCU.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_PCU = Convert.ToSingle(TB_PCU.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_RM = Convert.ToSingle(TB_RM.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_RCM = Convert.ToSingle(TB_RCM.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_CP = Convert.ToSingle(TB_CP.Text);
            information.CollectionRows_OO = Convert.ToSingle(TB_OO.Text);
            WPFDataGrid.Items.Add(information);
            TB_Obr.Focus();
            k++;
        }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        temp = false;
        if (TB_Obr.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToSingle(TB_Obr.Text) == 0)
            {
                title = "Ошибка № 2";
                message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                message_bold = "\"№ образца!\"";
                message_continius = " Поле не может начинаться с цифры \"0\"";
                Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                error.ShowDialog();
                TB_Obr.Focus();
                TB_Obr.SelectAll();
            }
            else
            {
                if (TB_Vn_vid.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    if (TB_zapax.Text.Length != 0)
                    {
                        if (TB_Vkyc.Text.Length != 0)
                        {
                            if (TB_Color.Text.Length != 0)
                            {
                                if (TB_CBPBBB.Text.Length != 0)
                                {
                                    if (TB_CFCU.Text.Length != 0)
                                    {
                                        if (TB_PCU.Text.Length != 0)
                                        {
                                            if (TB_RM.Text.Length != 0)
                                            {
                                                if (TB_RCM.Text.Length != 0)
                                                {
                                                    if (TB_CP.Text.Length != 0)
                                                    {
                                                        if (TB_OO.Text.Length != 0)
                                                        {
                                                            if (k == 0)
                                                            {
                                                                добавление_в_таблицу();
                                                                очистка_текстовых_полей();
                                                                изменение = false;
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (massive[i, 0] == Convert.ToInt32(TB_Obr.Text))
                                                                    {
                                                                        temp = true;
                                                                        title = "Ошибка № 14";
                                                                        message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                                                        message_bold = "\"№ образца!\"";
                                                                        message_continius = " Такой образец с \"№ " + massive[i, 0] + "\" уже существует в таблице";
                                                                        Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                                                        error.ShowDialog();
                                                                        TB_Obr.Focus();
                                                                        TB_Obr.SelectAll();
                                                                        break;
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                if (temp == false)
                                                                {
                                                                    добавление_в_таблицу();
                                                                    очистка_текстовых_полей();
                                                                    изменение = false;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            title = "Ошибка № 13";
                                                            message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                                            message_bold = "\"Окраска окорока!\"";
                                                            message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                                            Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                                            error.ShowDialog();
                                                            TB_OO.Focus();
                                                            TB_OO.SelectAll();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        title = "Ошибка № 12";
                                                        message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                                        message_bold = "\"Структура пористости!\"";
                                                        message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                                        Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                                        error.ShowDialog();
                                                        TB_CP.Focus();
                                                        TB_CP.SelectAll();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    title = "Ошибка № 11";
                                                    message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                                    message_bold = "\"Реологические свойства мякиша!\"";
                                                    message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                                    Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                                    error.ShowDialog();
                                                    TB_RCM.Focus();
                                                    TB_RCM.SelectAll();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                title = "Ошибка № 10";
                                                message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                                message_bold = "\"Разжевываемость мякиша!\"";
                                                message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                                Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                                error.ShowDialog();
                                                TB_RM.Focus();
                                                TB_RM.SelectAll();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            title = "Ошибка № 9";
                                            message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                            message_bold = "\"Прочность сваренных изделий!\"";
                                            message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                            Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                            error.ShowDialog();
                                            TB_PCU.Focus();
                                            TB_PCU.SelectAll();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        title = "Ошибка № 8";
                                        message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                        message_bold = "\"Сохранность формы сваренных изделий!\"";
                                        message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                        Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                        error.ShowDialog();
                                        TB_CFCU.Focus();
                                        TB_CFCU.SelectAll();
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    title = "Ошибка № 7";
                                    message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                    message_bold = "\"Сухое вещество, перешедшее в варочную воду!\"";
                                    message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                    Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                    error.ShowDialog();
                                    TB_CBPBBB.Focus();
                                    TB_CBPBBB.SelectAll();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                title = "Ошибка № 6";
                                message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                                message_bold = "\"Цвет!\"";
                                message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                                Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                                error.ShowDialog();
                                TB_Color.Focus();
                                TB_Color.SelectAll();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            title = "Ошибка № 5";
                            message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                            message_bold = "\"Вкус!\"";
                            message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                            Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                            error.ShowDialog();
                            TB_Vkyc.Focus();
                            TB_Vkyc.SelectAll();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        title = "Ошибка № 4";
                        message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                        message_bold = "\"Запах!\"";
                        message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                        Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                        error.ShowDialog();
                        TB_zapax.Focus();
                        TB_zapax.SelectAll();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    title = "Ошибка № 3";
                    message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
                    message_bold = "\"Внешний вид!\"";
                    message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
                    Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
                    error.ShowDialog();
                    TB_Vn_vid.Focus();
                    TB_Vn_vid.SelectAll();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            title = "Ошибка № 1";
            message = "Допущена ошибка в текстовом блоке ";
            message_bold = "\"№ образца!\"";
            message_continius = " Поле не может быть пустым";
            Error error = new Error(title, message, message_bold, message_continius);
            error.ShowDialog();
            TB_Obr.Focus();
            TB_Obr.SelectAll();
        }
    }
```

Да, выше написанный код реализация передачи данных из текстовых боксов в массив, из массива в datagrid все выглядит не очень, но на первое время пойдет.

А это код для экспорта в excel на C#

```
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        excel.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
        Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        for (int j = 0; j < WPFDataGrid_result.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1];
            sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
            myRange.Value2 = WPFDataGrid_result.Columns[j].Header;
            sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGray;
            sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 3d;
            sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 3d;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < WPFDataGrid_result.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < WPFDataGrid_result.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock b = WPFDataGrid_result.Columns[i].GetCellContent(WPFDataGrid_result.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
                //Console.WriteLine(b.Text);
                myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
                myRange.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 3d;
                myRange.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 3d;
                column = j;
            }
            row = column + 3;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < WPFDataGrid1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1 + row, j + 1];
            sheet1.Cells[1 + row, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
            myRange.Value2 = WPFDataGrid1.Columns[j].Header;
            sheet1.Cells[1 + row, j + 1].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGray;
            sheet1.Cells[1 + row, j + 1].Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 3d;
            sheet1.Cells[1 + row, j + 1].Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 3d;
            column = j;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < WPFDataGrid1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < WPFDataGrid1.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock b = WPFDataGrid1.Columns[i].GetCellContent(WPFDataGrid1.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[row + j + 2, i + 1];
                myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
                myRange.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 3d;
                myRange.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 3d;
                //Console.WriteLine((j + 1) + ", " + одинаковые_образцы[i] + ";");
                if ((j + 1) == одинаковые_образцы[i])
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < WPFDataGrid1.Columns.Count; z++)
                    {
                        myRange.Cells[1, z + 1 - i].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        sheet1.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Comment: Если возникнут дополнительные вопросы, можно задать в [Telegram](https://prnt.sc/11p8j89) Там можно более детально рассмотреть код, работоспособность и т.д.

Comment: То есть, мы должны бегать за вами по всяким телеграммам, чтоб решить вашу проблему? Не кажется это бредовым? Здесь наоборот, вы должны предоставить нам как можно больше информации о вашей проблеме, чтоб у нас вовсе не возникало каких-либо вопросов! Также не забывайте, что SO не форум, а сайт, где сообщество собирает полезную **не только для вас** информацию. Касательно скриншотов, они должны быть вставлены в вопрос, чтоб мы их видели сразу, а не переходили по ссылкам, я допустим недавно бан на LightShot получил, вот написал раз парсер, отправил кучу запросов и забанили меня на некое время.

Comment: Касательно вашей проблемы... Знаете, в чем она состоит? `Я раньше работал с WindowsForm`, то есть вы пытаетесь применить подход WinForm в WPF проекте, когда они кардинально отличаются друг от друга. Научитесь работать по правилам WPF, поймите что такое XAML, зачем он, поймите как работают базовые вещи - привязки. У вас не должно быть в коде вовсе каких либо `as TextBlock;` или других обращений к UI, у вас должны быть классы и свойства, которые XAML сам прочитает и выдаст указанный вид.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, помогите разобраться в этой проблеме немного

Comment: ошибки нужно добавлять текстом а не скриншотом

Comment: @DarthKYL, исправил

Comment: `помогите разобраться в этой проблеме` - с той, что в вопросе? Я вам уже сказал как должно у вас все быть. Ну а если нужны костыли, то очевидно ведь, что у вас `WPFDataGrid_result.Columns[i].GetCellContent(WPFDataGrid_result.Items[j])` либо вовсе нету данных по указанным индексам, либо тот объект, что вы получаете не является `TextBlock`. Проводите отладку, смотрите какие "колонки" вы пытаетесь взять, смотрите что там, какие объекты и так далее. Ну и также посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, с индексами все в порядке. Проблема в том, что все что спрятано, то что находится внизу, он видит как пустоту или если проскролить в самый низ, то он сразу выдаст Null при экспортирования, якобы нет первоначальных значений, а такого быть не может. Я не первый месяц решаю эту проблему. Я не знаю других способов, как можно вывести это в excel со стилями. Если говорить просто о выводе в excel данные, то можно обойтись ClipboardCopyMode, но он меня не устраивает