# Присвоить значение свойству класса

Tags: c#

Как правильно присвоить значение свойству класса, а затем вывести его?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public class Model1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
    public string Property7 { get; set; }
    public string Property8 { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Model1 = new Model1();
        Model1.Model2.Property5 = "123";
        //Model1.Model2.Property5 = "123";
        Console.WriteLine(Model1.Model2.Property5);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/213987

Answer (score 3):

```
    var Model1 = new Model1();
    Model1.Model2 = new Model2();
    Model1.Model2.Property5 = "123";
```

---

```
    var Model1 = new Model1() {
      Model2 = new Model2() {
        Property5 = "123"
      }
    };
```