# Инициализация полей

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь проинициализировать поля и во всех случаях получаю такую ошибку ( System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.), подскажите что я делаю неверно?
Это мои поля:

```
public DateRange BookedOnDate { get; set; }

/*
public class DateRange
    {
        public LocalDate Start { get; set; }

        public LocalDate End { get; set; }
    } 
*/

public IncludedReservationType IncludedReservationType { get; set; }
/*
public enum IncludedReservationType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "All Reservation")]
        AllReservation = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value = "Arrivals")]
        Arrivals = 2
    } 
*/

public IEnumerable<ReservationCategories> ReservationCategories { get; set; }

/*
public enum ReservationCategories
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Unpaid")]
        UnpaidBalance = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value = "Unassigned")]
        UnassignedRoom = 2,

        [EnumMember(Value = "No Payment Method")]
        NoPaymentMethod = 3
    } 
*/
```

А это я пытаюсь инициализировать, поправьте, где я ошибаюсь, пожалуйста:

```
            DateRange bookedOnDateRange = new DateRange();
            bookedOnDateRange.Start = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 02);
            bookedOnDateRange.End = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 04);

            BookedOnDate = bookedOnDateRange; //Object reference not set to an instance of an object

            IncludedReservationType = IncludedReservationType.AllReservation; //Object reference not set to an instance of an object

            var reservationCategories = new List<ReservationCategories> { 
            ReservationCategories.UnpaidBalance };
            reportRequest.AdvancedInput.ReservationCategories = reservationCategories;   //Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

---

UPD:
На данный момент я пытаюсь создать unit test для repository, где я получаю данные из БД и там же применяю необходимую фильтрацию. Для того чтобы вызвать требуемый метод, мне необходимо отправить туда входные данные, и тут я занимаюсь заполнением этих полей в ручную и затем пытаюсь вызвать метод из repository.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;


namespace innRoad.Reports.Data.Tests.Repository
{
    public partial class ReservationCardsRepositoryTests 
    {
        private readonly TestBuilder _testBuilder = new TestBuilder();
       
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetReservationsWithUnPaidBalance_ShouldReturnRequiredReservations()
        {
            var clientId = xxx;
            var propertyId = yyy;

            DateRange stayedOnDateRange = new DateRange();
            stayedOnDateRange.Start = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 01);
            stayedOnDateRange.End = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 03);

            DateRange bookedOnDateRange = new DateRange();
            bookedOnDateRange.Start = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 02);
            bookedOnDateRange.End = new NodaTime.LocalDate(2021, 04, 04);

            var reportRequest = new ReportRequest();
            reportRequest.StayOnDate = stayedOnDateRange;
            reportRequest.AdvancedInput.BookedOnDate.Start = new NodaTime.LocalDate();
            reportRequest.AdvancedInput.BookedOnDate.End = new NodaTime.LocalDate();
            // bookedOnDateRange;
            //reportRequest.AdvancedInput.BookedOnDate.End = bookedOnDateRange.End;
            reportRequest.Input.IncludedReservationType = IncludedReservationType.AllReservation;
            reportRequest.ClientId = clientId;
            reportRequest.PropertyId = propertyId;

            var reservationCategories = new List<ReservationCategories> { ReservationCategories.UnpaidBalance };
            reportRequest.AdvancedInput.ReservationCategories = reservationCategories;

            var repository = _testBuilder.Build();
            var filteredByReservationCategories = repository.GetReservationBaseQueryAsync(reportRequest);
            //var baseReservations = filteredByReservationCategories;

            Assert.NotNull(filteredByReservationCategories);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше кода, чтобы понять. `А это я пытаюсь инициализировать` где этот код находится? `Это мои поля:` - это на самом деле свойства, а не поля. Не видно, часть чего эти совйства, и где вы это что-то создаете например с помощью `new`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Я добавил описания для понимания происходящего

Comment: Код, который вы добавили отличается от кода, в котором у вас указаны ошибки. Следовательно непонятно, где там в юнит-тесте у вас крашится, и крашится ли вообще и на какой именно строке.