# Почему в Unity File>Build Settings>Android>Player Settings>Player ничего не высвечивается? Как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Когда открывается окно Player Settings, высвечиваются две ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста это исправить!

Comment: Какие ошибки? Что пишет?

Comment: Прикреплен скрин консоли. Там появляются ошибки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Первая ошибка говорит об `GetVREnabledDevicesOnTargetGroup` и `OnEnable`  методе что вызывается при открытии окна, я поискал по нему и в основном нахожу что то связанное с `SteamVR`, стоит покапать в эту сторону, вторая ошибка говорит об отсутствии запрашиваемого объекта  SetValueChangeListeners. Я предполагаю что это связанно с тем что возможно какое нибудь устройство подсоединено по USB, и я бы попробывал переустановить unity на более стабильную LTS версию, и проверил все подключаемые пакеты как SteamVR к примеру

Comment: @Alemkhan Utepkaliev, спасибо!

Comment: @Максим Фисман, нет, мне кажется, это разные вопросы

Comment: @CATpython, Держите меня в курсе если найдете ответ или какие нибудь ещё зацепки, вопрос очень интересный может сможем решить его вместе. Для сообщества это будет полезный вклад

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Слева от вопроса, под кнопками голосования, над кнопкой истории действий над постом есть кнопка "добавить в закладки". Если вы добавите вопрос в закладки, то вам будут приходить уведомления о всех действиях над вопросом.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, не знал, отлично, спасибо!

Comment: @Alemkhan Utepkaliev, спасибо, мне тоже очень интересно найти ответ на вопрос. Надеюсь исправить эту ошибку в ближайшее время.