# Как создать систему таймеров в игре без дубляжа кода в Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, разработка-игр

В моей игре довольно много таймеров, из-за чего возникает проблема дубляжа кода корутин и буллевых полей. Я написал систему таймеров, которая позволяет создав экземпляр класса Timer, через конструктор задать время кулдауна, после чего запускается корутина. При запуске следующего кода я получаю кучу NullReferenceException на строку из класса Player, где я вызываю метод StartTimer(), и на вызов корутины в методе StartTimer().
В чём я ошибся? Как написать более гибкую систему?

Код игрока:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WeaponSwitcher _weaponSwitcher;
    private Cooldown _shootCooldown = new Cooldown(0.5f);
    private Stats _playerStats = new Stats(15f); //первый аргумент - мувспид
    private bool _switchWeaponKey, _shootKey,_moveRightKey,_moveLeftKey;
    private void Start()
    {
        _weaponSwitcher = GetComponent<WeaponSwitcher>();
        _shootCooldown.action = _weaponSwitcher.currentWeapon.Shoot;
    }
    private void EnterInput()
    {
        _switchWeaponKey = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1);
        _shootKey = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        _moveRightKey = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
        _moveLeftKey = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        EnterInput();
        if (_switchWeaponKey) _weaponSwitcher.SwitchWeapon();
        if (_shootKey && _shootCooldown.canDoAction)
        {
            _shootCooldown.StartTimer();
        }
        if (_moveRightKey)
        {
            _playerStats.direction = Vector2.right;
            transform.Translate(_playerStats.direction * _playerStats.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (_moveLeftKey)
        {
            _playerStats.direction = Vector2.left;
            transform.Translate(_playerStats.direction * _playerStats.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Код таймера:

```
public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _cooldownTime;
    public delegate void Action();
    public Action action;
    public bool canDoAction = true;
    public Cooldown(float cooldownTime)
    {
        _cooldownTime = cooldownTime;
    }
    public void StartTimer() => StartCoroutine(ICooldown());
    private IEnumerator ICooldown()
    {
        canDoAction = false;
        action();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_cooldownTime);
        canDoAction = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `NullReferenceException` то знаете, что такое?

Comment: честно, не особо. Знаю, что возникает тогда, когда вызывается что-то, чего нет.

Comment: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413042/373567)

Answer (score 1):

Я действительно сглупил, ответ был простой как палка. Как оказалось, вызывать корутины в экземплярах класса нельзя, нужно вешать скрипт на нужный объект на сцене.