# Массиву не присваеваеться значение

Tags: c#

```
namespace Console_Serep
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ReadedReport json = File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadedReport>(File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) : new ReadedReport();

            while (true)
            {
                switch (Console.ReadLine())
                {
                    case "/rep":
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите отчет в формате 00 00 00:00 00 00");
                        string rep = Console.ReadLine();
                        int id = json.Items == null ? 0 : json.Items.Length;
                        json.Items[id] = new Converter(rep).Report;
                        File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Такой команды не предусмотренно, попробуйте ввести другую или проверить наличие опечаток");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ReadedReport
    {
        public Report[] Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` - эта ошибка возникает на строке записи в файл.

Элементу массива json.Items[id] не присваивается значение объекта, типы данных массива и присваиваемого объекта совпадают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как можно сделать иначе.

Comment: Код и все сообщения об ошибках - текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` это каталог, а имя файла где? `File.WriteAllText("file.json", ...);`

Comment: Покажите код класса `ReadedReport`, или скажите, какой тип у `Items`.

Comment: namespace Console_Serep
{
    class ReadedReport
    {
        public Report[] Items { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Converter тоже возвращает Report

Comment: Когда вы создаёте `new ReadedReport`, свойство `Items` равно `null`. Следовательно, тут `json.Items[id]` выбрасывается ваше исключение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
public Report[] Items { get; set; }
```

Массив имеет фиксированное количество элементов, которое задается при создании массива, например `new Report[4]`. В массив нельзя динамически добавлять элементы.

Используйте список вместо массива.

```cs
public List<Report> Items { get; set; }
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть вот так:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Введите отчет в формате 00 00 00:00 00 00");
string rep = Console.ReadLine();
if (json.Items == null)
    json.Items = new List<Report>();
json.Items.Add(new Converter(rep).Report);
```

На работу с JSON сериализацией изменение типа этого свойства повлиять никак не должно.

И обязательно прочитайте вот это: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/373567)