# Не могу реализовать прыжок в Unity для мобилок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только начинаю разрабатывать мобильные игры. Использую Phonton Pun 2 free для мультиплеера.
Мне нужно добавить прыжок по кнопке на экране. Посмотрел и сделал как в туторе, с поправочкой на Phonton, но увы код не работает. Подскажите, что я сделал не так. Пытался по разному перебирать воздействия, приводящие к прыжку, но в итоге при нажатии на кнопку ошибка :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
move.jump() (at Assets/scripts/move.cs:23)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at <d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193>:0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at <d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193>:0)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:68)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:110)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:262)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)
```

мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class move : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    private float x,y;
    public float speed;

    private Joystick joystick;
    private PhotonView view;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start() {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        view=GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        joystick= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<Joystick>();
    }

    public void jump(){
        y = joystick.Vertical*speed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0,y);
    }

    void Update() {
        x = joystick.Horizontal*speed;
        if(view.IsMine){
            jump();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(x,0);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Кнопку просто через ui вызвал и добавил phonton view, при нажатии вызываю JUMP, если что-то ещё понадобится, то могу скинуть.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: немного не то. Я знаю как сделать движение, но после добавления модуля Phonton возникли проблемы с функциями внутри кода ( он их просто не видит или типо того)

Comment: В функции `jump` на 23 строчке та ошибка: `move.jump() (at Assets/scripts/move.cs:23)`. Выведите по-строчно значения `joystick`, `joystick.Vertical` и `speed`, думаю поможет понять какой неправильный.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, Вы забыли проинициализировать переменную `speed`, из-за этого её значение для всего кода пустое (т.е. равно `null`). Как следствие, при попытке вычислить выражение со `speed` программа пытается перемножить `null` с другой переменной и при этом выбрасывает `NullPointerException`.

Более подробная информация об этом исключении, а также способы её решения прилагаю в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413042) ответе.

Comment: Но веду у меня тип float и он не может быть null, к тому же, если я конечно правильно понял ваш ответ, я в Jump() присвоил y значение joystick'а.
'''    public void jump(){
        
        y = joystick.Vertical*speed;
        if (y){
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0,y);
        }

    }
'''