# Не знаю как исправить ошибку , выглядит довольно странно

Tags: c#, авторизация

Делаю сайт на шарпах и дело дошло до авторизации пользователя .
использую данную конструкцию "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" во вьюшке , все нормально отрабатывает и не возникает никаких вопросов , но когда использую её же в контроллере , то выдает "System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."" , в чем может быть дело ?

Comment: Ну, очевидно, в контроллере переменной не присвоено значение. Без кода ничего конкретнее не сказать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: в контроллере я просто использую условие " if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)"

Comment: Дело в том, что какая-то переменная является null. Проверьте экземпляр класса User, его свойства Identity и IsAuthenticated с помощью отладчика. Скорее всего, что-то из этого является null. Инфа по этому исключению - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)