# Ошибка .NET 6.0 NullReferenceException в Speech Recognition Engine, которой нет в .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, null, распознавание-речи

Пишу простейшее приложение с распознаванием речи, один и тот же код работает на .NET 4.8, но не работает на .NET 6.0. В строке `SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(cultureInfo);` возникает ошибка System.NullReferenceException. В .NET 4.8 в этой строке  ошибки не возникает. Что необходимо поменять, чтобы код заработал на .NET 6.0?

```
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SpeechRecognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Label label;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static void _SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.82) label.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label = label1;

            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-ru");
            SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(cultureInfo);
            speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized +=
                new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_SpeechRecognized);

            Choices numbers = new Choices();
            numbers.Add(new string[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять" });

            GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            grammarBuilder.Append(numbers);

            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
            speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);

            speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/422180

Comment: `new CultureInfo("ru-RU");`

Comment: _В случае .NET 4.8 в этой строке в переменной speechRecognitionEngine также записан null_ - неправда, конструктор не может вернуть null, это даже теоретически невозможно. Вы просто отладчиком на следующую строчку кода перейдите, а то смотрите в ещё неприсвоенную переменную.

Comment: @aepot, `ru-RU` автоматически подставляется.

Comment: Стек вызовов при возникновении ошибки покажите.

Comment: @user7860670,
Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.HKEYfromRegKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey)
    Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.RootHKEYFromRegPath(string)
    Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.Open(string, bool)
    Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()
    Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognitionEngine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    SpeechRecognition.Form1.Form1_Shown(object, System.EventArgs) в Form1.cs

Comment: Не в комментарий, отредактируйте сам вопрос. Выложите полный трейс туда.